# How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, selectall

I have an HTML page with multiple checkboxes.

I need one more checkbox by the name "select all". When I select this checkbox all checkboxes in the HTML page must be selected. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to degrade gracefully, selecting the "select all" should actually mean that all are selected regardless of their individual state. (visiting your page with javascript disabled)

Comment: In Firefox (and maybe others?) : Hit `CTRL+SHIFT+K` to open the console, then **paste** : `$("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true)` and hit `Enter`.  All check-boxes on current page should now be checked. **To un-check** change `True` to `False`.

Answer (score 379):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

**UPDATE:**

The `for each...in` construct doesn't seem to work, at least in this case, in Safari 5 or Chrome 5. This code should work in all browsers:

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)

---------------------------------------
should:
 for(var checkbox in checkboxes)

Comment: @HelloWorld: for each...in is actually valid Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for_each...in But, as porneL has pointed out, it's an obscure construct. Also, this code doesn't work in Safari 5 or Chrome 5. It works in FF 3.6, and IIRC, it worked in Safari 4. `for(var i in checkboxes) checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked` works in all browsers.

Comment: If adopting this for jquery, remember that the source variable becomes an EventHandler class, for click events, so you need to specify the target object for the checked command to work. See my answer below.

Comment: @CanBerkGüder What if you wanted the check all boxes on one page? One check all to control one set of checkboxes and another check all to control another set.

Comment: Never use `for in` with a collection or array

Comment: I was having a problem using this code. For me I had to change the function name.

Comment: for a complete answer, i am wondering how you would uncheck the "Toggle All" checkbox in the case where: (1) Toggle All is checked; (2) any of checkboxes where name="foo" is then unchecked?

Comment: Why do you do `, n=checkboxes.length;i<n` instead of just `i < checkboxes.length`? Anyway, to make the function generic (code reuse), pass an additional parameter: `(source, checkboxes_name)` and do `document.getElementsByName(checkboxes_name);` It's better than hard-coding the name and making the function specific to a particular set of checkboxes.

Comment: All checkboxes have the same name? How can you tell them from one another after the form is posted?

Comment: @mplungjan is there any sound reasoning behind your recommendation or is that just preference?

Comment: @Typel for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: @ADTC It is good practice to set a variable to the length of the array to stop the chance for an infinite loop. If somewhere in your loop you add another checkbox the loop would never end as the length is always increasing.

Comment: Always Declare Local Variables

Comment: Alright, as my edit was rejected for some reason, I guess I'll comment here. The for-each construct is deprecated and **will not work!** You have to use its replacement: `for(let checkbox of checkboxes)`.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that having multiple checkboxes with the same name is invalid html. It serves the purpose of demonstrating the functionality here, but this being a very popular question, it'd be wise (for the sake of inexperienced future readers) to use a different selector (e.g. to assign a class to all the checkboxes we wish to handle this way).

Comment: `function toggle(source) {` `Array.from(document.getElementsByName(source.name))`
`.filter(checkbox => checkbox !== source)`
`.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = source.checked);`
`}`
then put the name for the toggle checkbox the same as for other checkboxes, and then no need to hardcode the name inside the function. What about a function like this?

Comment: @El_Vanja No, multiple names is perfectly OK and valid. This sets it apart from `id`.

Comment: @naton OK, maybe purely by the HTML standard it is valid (you would need identical names for e.g. a radio button); however, in this case it will not be functional HTML. When you submit such a form, you will only receive the value of the last checked box with that name.

Answer (score 161):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```js
// Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;                       
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" />

<!-- select all boxes -->
<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />
```

Comment: i'd add an else clause to handle the deselect use case, ;-)
..
else
{
// Iterate each checkbox
$(":checkbox").each(function() {
this.checked = false;
});

            }

Comment: If you want to leave out the if and else and still handle the deselect you can do it this way : 
var state = this.checked;
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
   this.checked = state;
});

Comment: You may be able to simplify this to `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);` and `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 97):

I'm not sure anyone hasn't answered in this way (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
  $( '#container .toggle-button' ).click( function () {
    $( '#container input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
  })
```

It's clean, has no loops or if/else clauses and works as a charm.

Comment: Slightly amending this to: `$('#container').on('click', 'toggle-button', function () {...})` is more performant because jQuery only needs to listen for click events from within `#container` rather than the entire DOM. See more in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 75):

I'm surprised no one mentioned [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Pure JavaScript solution, works in IE9+.

```js
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != source)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" />Check all?<br />

<input type="checkbox" />Bar 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Bar 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Bar 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Bar 4<br />
```

Comment: this worked in Chrome, but i had a lot of checkboxes for different reasons, so instead of targeting 'type="checkbox"', i targeted 'name="myobject"' and it also worked.

Comment: Maybe this should be changed to the new correct answer, if not some discussion would be helpful. :-)

Comment: This answer was a lot easier to implement into existing pages than the other answers. good job.

Answer (score 67):

here's a different way  less code

```
$(function () {
       $('#select-all').click(function (event) {
          
           var selected = this.checked;
           // Iterate each checkbox
           $(':checkbox').each(function () {    this.checked = selected; });

       });
    });
```

Answer (score 16):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/H37cb/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" /></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function(){
var status = $(this).is(':checked');
$('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', status);
});

});
</script>




<div id="wrapper">
 <li style="margin-top: 20px">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" /> <label for='all'>All</label>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title_1" /> <label for="title_1"><strong>Title 01</strong></label>
    <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_1" value="1" /> <label for="box_1">Sub Title 01</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_2" value="2" /> <label for="box_2">Sub Title 02</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_3" value="3" /> <label for="box_3">Sub Title 03</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_4" value="4" /> <label for="box_4">Sub Title 04</label></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title_2" /> <label for="title_2"><strong>Title 02</strong></label>
    <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_5" value="5" /> <label for="box_5">Sub Title 05</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_6" value="6" /> <label for="box_6">Sub Title 06</label></li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_7" value="7" /> <label for="box_7">Sub Title 07</label></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: For me it's only working for a single cycle.It toggles only once then it does nothing.

Comment: So it's the `attr()` method I guess. changed it to `prop()`

Comment: Well, if I deselect any item from the list shouldn't be the Select All checkbox deselected too?

Answer (score 13):

When you call `document.getElementsByName("name")`, you will get a `Object`. Use `.item(index)` to traverse all items of a `Object`

HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByName('rfile')) document.getElementsByName('rfile').item(c).checked = this.checked">

<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​cgi-bin/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​includes/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​misc/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​modules/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​profiles/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​scripts/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​sites/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​stats/​">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"rfile" value=​"/​themes/​">​
```

Comment: if I need an if condition inside the onclick, how can I add it? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Slightly changed version which checks and unchecks respectfully

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
        var $that = $(this);
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = $that.is(':checked');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

My simple solution allows to selectively select/deselect all checkboxes **in a given portion of the form**, while using **different names** for each checkbox, so that they can be easily recognized after the form is POSTed.

Javascript:

```
function setAllCheckboxes(divId, sourceCheckbox) {
    divElement = document.getElementById(divId);
    inputElements = divElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
        if (inputElements[i].type != 'checkbox')
            continue;
        inputElements[i].checked = sourceCheckbox.checked;
    }
}
```

HTML example:

```
<p><input onClick="setAllCheckboxes('actors', this);" type="checkbox" />All of them</p>
<div id="actors">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="kevin" />Spacey, Kevin</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="colin" />Firth, Colin</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="scarlett" />Johansson, Scarlett</p>
</div>
```

I hope you like it!

Answer (score 9):

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function do_this(){

        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('approve[]');
        var button = document.getElementById('toggle');

        if(button.value == 'select'){
            for (var i in checkboxes){
                checkboxes[i].checked = 'FALSE';
            }
            button.value = 'deselect'
        }else{
            for (var i in checkboxes){
                checkboxes[i].checked = '';
            }
            button.value = 'select';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="3" />

<input type="button" id="toggle" value="select" onClick="do_this()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple JQuery:

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)`, no need for the conditional.

Answer (score 9):

It's rather simple:

```
const selectAllCheckboxes = () => {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkboxes.forEach((cb) => { cb.checked = true; });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This sample works with native JavaScript where the checkbox variable name varies, i.e. not all "foo."

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Toggling checkboxes</p>
<script>
function getcheckboxes() {
    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var checkboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) 
    {
        var node = node_list[i];
        if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') 
        {
            checkboxes.push(node);
        }
    } 
    return checkboxes;
}
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = getcheckboxes();
    for (var i = 0 n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) 
    {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
</script>    

<input type="checkbox" name="foo1" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo2" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo3" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo4" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `getcheckboxes` function could be replaced with `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');`

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript is your best bet.  The link below gives an example using buttons to de/select all.  You could try to adapt it to use a check box, just use you 'select all' check box' onClick attribute.

[Javascript Function to Check or Uncheck all Checkboxes](http://www.somacon.com/p117.php)

This page has a simpler example

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_onClick.html

Answer (score 5):

If adopting the top answer for jQuery, remember that the object passed to the click function is an EventHandler, not the original checkbox object. Therefore code should be modified as follows.

HTML

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="selectThemAll"/> Toggle All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    jQuery("[name=selectThemAll]").click(function(source) { 
        checkboxes = jQuery("[name=foo]");
        for(var i in checkboxes){
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.target.checked;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: not only is the first input type wrong, but even after correcting it this did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Select All" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
<br />
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 5">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item 6">Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(obj1) {
        var checkboxCollection = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxCollection.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxCollection[i].type.toString().toLowerCase() == "checkbox") {
                checkboxCollection[i].checked = obj1.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

that should do the job done:

```
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have **different sets of checkboxes on the same form**.  Here is a solution that selects/unselects checkboxes by class name, using vanilla javascript function **document.getElementsByClassName**

The Select All button

```
<input type='checkbox' id='select_all_invoices' onclick="selectAll()"> Select All
```

Some of the checkboxes to select

```
<input type='checkbox' class='check_invoice' id='check_123' name='check_123' value='321' />
<input type='checkbox' class='check_invoice' id='check_456' name='check_456' value='852' />
```

The javascript

```
    function selectAll() {
        var blnChecked = document.getElementById("select_all_invoices").checked;
        var check_invoices = document.getElementsByClassName("check_invoice");
        var intLength = check_invoices.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < intLength; i++) {
            var check_invoice = check_invoices[i];
            check_invoice.checked = blnChecked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does work.  Please check out https://codepen.io/kustomweb/pen/gZqwLV

Answer (score 3):

This is what this will do, for instance if you have 5 checkboxes, and you click check all,it check all, now if you uncheck all the checkbox probably by clicking each 5 checkboxs, by the time you uncheck the last checkbox, the select all checkbox also gets unchecked

```
$("#select-all").change(function(){
   $(".allcheckbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
  })
  $(".allcheckbox").change(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
          $("#select-all").prop("checked", false)
      }
      if($(".allcheckbox:checked").length == $(".allcheckbox").length){
          $("#select-all").prop("checked", true)
      }
  })
```

Comment: The `.prop()` solved my problem... `.attr()` or `.checked =` didn't :/

Answer (score 3):

As I cannot comment, here as answer:
I would write Can Berk Güder's solution in a more general way,
so you may reuse the function for other checkboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleCheckboxes(source, cbName) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(cbName);
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
</script>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleCheckboxes(this,\'foo\')" /> Toggle All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar5"> Bar 5<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks khaldi and Clarity for pointing out the missing bracket!

Comment: The `language` attribute on `script` elements was [deprecated long ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#deprecated_attributes). If you must add an attribute (and there is no requirement to do so), use the `type` attribute with the appropriate MIME type. See also [HTML Script tag: type or language (or omit both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2267476/215552)

Comment: Ok, thank you Heretic Monkey! I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).on(' change', 'input[name="check_all"]', function() {
                    $('.cb').prop("checked", this.checked);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery and knockout:

With this binding main checkbox stays in sync with underliying checkboxes, it will be unchecked unless all checkboxes checked.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.allChecked = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var selector = valueAccessor();

    function getChecked () {
      element.checked = $(selector).toArray().every(function (checkbox) {
        return checkbox.checked;
      });
    }

    function setChecked (value) {
      $(selector).toArray().forEach(function (checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked !== value) {
          checkbox.click();
        }
      });
    }

    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'click', function (event) {
      setChecked(event.target.checked);
    });

    $(window.document).on('change', selector, getChecked);

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, () => {
      $(window.document).off('change', selector, getChecked);
    });

    getChecked();
  }
};
```

in html:

```
<input id="check-all-values" type="checkbox" data-bind="allChecked: '.checkValue'"/>
<input id="check-1" type="checkbox" class="checkValue"/>
<input id="check-2" type="checkbox" class="checkValue"/>
```

Comment: I don't know enough about knockout (I am using ko3.4 from cdnjs.cloudflare.com but the above seems not to work - at all. I can set a breakpoint on the initial init: call which gets triggered when the page loads( which I assume is correct), but stepping into this yields nothing - none of the rest of the function is executed. Setting breakpoint on the other functions, and they never get triggered.

Comment: Tony Suffolk, there art two event handlers set: onclick and onchange for checkbox, and checkbox value is updated at the end of the code. If this code does not work in your project, check data-bind attribute for checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

to make it in short-hand version by using jQuery

The select all checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll">
```

The children checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkDel">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkDel">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkDel">
```

jQuery

```
$("#chkSelectAll").on('click', function(){
     this.checked ? $(".chkDel").prop("checked",true) : $(".chkDel").prop("checked",false);  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Below methods are very Easy to understand and you can implement existing forms in minutes

> With Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check-all').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
  });
  $('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

in HTML form put below buttons

```
<a id="check-all" href="javascript:void(0);">check all</a>
<a id="uncheck-all" href="javascript:void(0);">uncheck all</a>
```

> With just using javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
{
  var checkboxes = new Array(); 
  checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
      checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

in HTML form put below buttons

```
<button onclick="javascript:checkAll('form3', true);" href="javascript:void();">check all</button>

<button onclick="javascript:checkAll('form3', false);" href="javascript:void();">uncheck all</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a backbone.js implementation:

```
events: {
    "click #toggleChecked" : "toggleChecked"
},
toggleChecked: function(event) {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('options');
    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = event.currentTarget.checked;
    }

},
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<input class='all' type='checkbox'> All
<input class='item' type='checkbox' value='1'> 1
<input class='item' type='checkbox' value='2'> 2
<input class='item' type='checkbox' value='3'> 3
```

javascript

```
$(':checkbox.all').change(function(){
  $(':checkbox.item').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Add the **onchange** event Handler

```
<th><INPUT type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]" /> </th>
```

2: Modify the code to handle checked/unchecked

```
 function checkAll(ele) {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (ele.checked) {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = true;
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please do not copy paste code, instead refer with a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282219/check-uncheck-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

You can Use This code.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("dlCheckAll4Delete");
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".dlMultiDelete");
  checkboxes.forEach(function (ele) {
    ele.checked = !!checkbox.checked;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code

```
$('.checkall').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.checkme').prop('checked', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but when dealing with a check all checkbox, I believe you should also handle the scenario for when you have the check all checkbox checked, and then unchecking one of the checkboxes below.

In that case it should automatically uncheck the check all checkbox.

Also when manually checking all the checkboxes, you should end up with the check all checkbox being automatically checked.

You need two event handlers, one for the check all box, and one for when clicking any of the single boxes below.

```
// HANDLES THE INDIVIDUAL CHECKBOX CLICKS
function client_onclick() {
    var selectAllChecked = $("#chk-clients-all").prop("checked");

    // IF CHECK ALL IS CHECKED, AND YOU'RE UNCHECKING AN INDIVIDUAL BOX, JUST UNCHECK THE CHECK ALL CHECKBOX.
    if (selectAllChecked && $(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        $("#chk-clients-all").prop("checked", false);
    } else { // OTHERWISE WE NEED TO LOOP THROUGH INDIVIDUAL CHECKBOXES AND SEE IF THEY ARE ALL CHECKED, THEN CHECK THE SELECT ALL CHECKBOX ACCORDINGLY.
        var allChecked = true;
        $(".client").each(function () {
            allChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
            if (!allChecked) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("#chk-clients-all").prop("checked", allChecked);
    }
}

// HANDLES THE TOP CHECK ALL CHECKBOX
function client_all_onclick() {
    $(".client").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

*Simple and to the POINT:*

jQuery - Upon Clicking a button or div or a label element. Check off all checkboxes on the page. Keep in mind you'll have to adjust :checkbox to make it more specific.

```
jQuery("#My-Button").click(function() {

  jQuery(':checkbox').each(function() {
    if(this.checked == true) {
      this.checked = false;                        
    } else {
      this.checked = true;                        
    }      
  });

});
```