# Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

I've been told not to use `for...in` with arrays in JavaScript. Why not?

Comment: I saw the recent question where someone said that to you, but they only meant for Arrays. It is considered bad practice for iterating through arrays but not necessarily for iterating through members of an object.

Comment: Lots of answers with "for" loops such as 'for (var i=0; i<hColl.length; i++) {}' compare to 'var i=hColl.length; while (i--) {}' which, when it is possible to use the latter form it is substantially faster.  I know this is tangential but thought I would add this bit.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss but that's reverse iteration. Is there another version of forward iteration that's faster?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - yes, it is reverse, however given a known limit, it allows optimum processing especially in older browsers by iteration over a known set vs an unknown set length by setting the limit first.  It is the nature of an interpreted language.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Good comment. One could also write the `for` loop as `for (var i = hColl.length; i--;) {}`, which should have a similar performance profile as the reverse `while` loop.

Comment: @Wynand use `var i = hCol1.length; for (i;i;i--;) {}` cache the i as it will make a difference, and simplify the test. - the older the browser, the more difference between `for` and `while` ALWAYS cache the "i" counter - and of course negative does not always fit the situation, and the negative while `obfuscate ` the code a bit for some people. and note `var i = 1000; for (i; i; i--) {}` and `var b =1000 for (b; b--;) {}` where i goes 1000 to 1 and b goes 999 to 0. - the older the browser, the more the while tends to favor for performance.

Comment: You can also be clever.
`for(var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; ++i) ...` is the fastest and best you can get with forward iteration.

Answer (score 1731, accepted):

The reason is that one construct:

```js
var a = []; // Create a new empty array.
a[5] = 5;   // Perfectly legal JavaScript that resizes the array.

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // Iterate over numeric indexes from 0 to 5, as everyone expects.
    console.log(a[i]);
}

/* Will display:
   undefined
   undefined
   undefined
   undefined
   undefined
   5
*/
```

can sometimes be totally different from the other:

```js
var a = [];
a[5] = 5;
for (var x in a) {
    // Shows only the explicitly set index of "5", and ignores 0-4
    console.log(x);
}

/* Will display:
   5
*/
```

Also consider that [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) libraries might do things like this, which will affect any array you create:

```js
// Somewhere deep in your JavaScript library...
Array.prototype.foo = 1;

// Now you have no idea what the below code will do.
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (var x in a){
    // Now foo is a part of EVERY array and 
    // will show up here as a value of 'x'.
    console.log(x);
}

/* Will display:
   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   foo
*/
```

Comment: Remember to use `(var x in a)` rather than `(x in a)` - don't want to create a global.

Comment: First issue isn't a reason it's bad, only a difference in semantics.  Second issue seems to me a reason (on top of clashes between libraries doing the same) that altering the prototype of a built-in datatype is bad, rather than that for..in is bad.

Comment: @Stewart. The 'difference in semantics' is actually a flaw in Javascript. The broken semantics mean the code doesn't do what you think it will, and that's why the construct is typically avoided.

Comment: Arrays in JS are associative - they just can be used as linear arrays.  As such, the whole point of using for..in is to iterate over the array's keys, whatever they may be.

Comment: @Stewart: **All objects** in JS are associative.  A JS Array is an object, so yes, it’s associative too, but that’s not what it’s for.  If you want to iterate over an object's _keys_, use `for (var key in object)`.  If you want to iterate over an array’s _elements_, however, use `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1)`.

Comment: I corrected `for(int i=0` to `for(var i=0`.  The first version produces a not-very-helpful "missing semi-colon" error (at least in Firefox).

Comment: So using built-in arrays as associative arrays is abusing the JS object model?  Is there any official recommendation on what to use for AAs instead?

Comment: You said for the first example, that it *Iterates over numeric indexes from 0 to 4, as everyone expects*, I **expect it to iterate from 0 to 5**! Since if you add an element in position 5, the array will have 6 elements (5 of them undefined).

Comment: This overall presents a problem in javascript, since the point of something like for..in is to be key-agnostic on objects or arrays. Quite the opposite, if you add something to array[5] you expect the array to have one item, with key 5, not five blank items that you didn't insert. You expect there to be in the array what you put in it! Unless you told the array explicitly to have five items, key '5' realistically should not indicate the number of items in the array. But this relates to what an array represents; in JSON arrays do not really have keys; to use the term key is misleading.

Comment: @stivlo - if you add an element only in position 5, the array will have 1 element as the `for..in` loop shows. There's a difference between an element that doesn't exist and so returns `undefined` when you try to access it and an element that does exist and returns `undefined` because that value has been explicitly assigned.

Comment: I think the examples would be even clearer if you set a[5] to something other than 5, say, a[5]=42. The fact that the second example ("for (x in a)" only enumerates one value is not surprising to me; the  fact that the value it enumerates is 5 instead of 42 is surprising to me (coming from other languages with a similar construct that enumerates list contents instead of array indices).

Comment: In the first example.. Would it be more efficient to _call_ a.length only once (and set to a var) prior to the loop? vs each time the loop iterates?

Comment: Augustum - yes, it would be more efficient. But it would also be more code, and would therefore illustrate the concept under question less directly.

Comment: `Object.keys(a).forEach( function(item) { console.log(item) } )` takes only real attributes, not those set in prototype.

Comment: @Martijin: Instead of the rather long and verbose `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1)` pattern, there is a new `for let value of object` function in the ES6 standard which is already supported in most modern browsers [See the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Under first example, in output part (`Will display:`), missed one `undefined`. Correct 5, not 4 `undefined`-s, I belive.  P.s. I can't edit posts.

Comment: Why doesn't the `for...in` iterate over all standard prototypes instead of just new `prototype` created like foo?

Comment: @Jonathan002 I wondered the same. So, `for...in` iterates only over [**enumerable properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). And `Array.prototype` methods are defined using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) which sets `enumerable` to `false` by default. If you were to use `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'foo', {
    value: 1 } )`, then `foo` won't be displayed

Comment: If you find a library which does something like `Array.prototype.foo = '...'`, you should report a bug as this code can have any number of unexpected side-effects. The correct way to do this is `Object.defineProperty(Array.protoype, 'foo', { enumerable: false, value: '...' })`!

Comment: This answer does a good job of explaining why not to use `for ... in` as a way to iterate over an array that is not fully defined, but that's just one (rather particular) edge case. It doesn't explain at all why it should not be used _in general_ or what's bad _in general_ about it. The answer could be equally rewritten to say nothing more than "if you use it iterate over a partially declared array it will only return the parts that are declared" without losing any value or information.

Comment: @TylerH It's generally bad because of the edge case. You REALLY don't want to track down that bug in a production system, so the best practice is to avoid the possibility.

Answer (score 431):

The `for-in` statement by itself is not a "bad practice", however it can be *mis-used*, for example, to *iterate* over arrays or array-like objects.

The purpose of the `for-in` statement is to *enumerate* over object properties. This statement will go up in the prototype chain, also enumerating over *inherited* properties, a thing that *sometimes* is not desired.

Also, the order of iteration is not guaranteed by the spec., meaning that if you want to "iterate" an array object, with this statement you cannot be sure that the properties (array indexes) will be visited in the numeric order.

For example, in JScript (IE <= 8), the order of enumeration even on Array objects is defined as the properties were created:

```
var array = [];
array[2] = 'c';
array[1] = 'b';
array[0] = 'a';

for (var p in array) {
  //... p will be "2", "1" and "0" on IE
}
```

Also, speaking about inherited properties, if you, for example, extend the `Array.prototype` object (like some libraries as MooTools do), that properties will be also enumerated:

```
Array.prototype.last = function () { return this[this.length-1]; };

for (var p in []) { // an empty array
  // last will be enumerated
}
```

As I said before to *iterate* over arrays or array-like objects, the best thing is to use a *sequential loop*, such as a plain-old `for`/`while` loop.

When you want to enumerate only the *own properties* of an object (the ones that aren't inherited), you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // prop is not inherited
  }
}
```

And some people even recommend calling the method directly from `Object.prototype` to avoid having problems if somebody adds a property named `hasOwnProperty` to our object:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
    // prop is not inherited
  }
}
```

Comment: See also David Humphrey's post [Iterating over Objects in JavaScript Quickly](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1205) - for array's `for..in` is much slower than "normal" loops.

Comment: Question about the last point about "hasOwnProperty": If someone overrides "hasOwnProperty" on an object, you'll have problems.  But won't you have the same problems if someone overrides "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty"?  Either way they're screwing you up and it's not your responsibility right?

Comment: You say `for..in` is not bad practice, but it can be misused. Have you got a real world example of good practice, where you really did want to go through all of an objects properties including inherited properties?

Comment: @ScottRippey: If you want to take it there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrFUI591WhI

Comment: with this answer I found that can access the value with `for (var p in array) {
  array[p];
}`

Comment: *Also, the order of iteration is not guaranteed by the spec* This is incorrect as of at least ES2015 and maybe before. Array indicies are guaranteed to be iterated over in ascending numeric order.

Answer (score 130):

There are three reasons why you shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate over array elements:

- `for..in` will loop over all own and inherited properties of the array object which aren't `DontEnum`; that means if someone adds properties to the specific array object (there are valid reasons for this - I've done so myself) or changed `Array.prototype` (which is considered bad practice in code which is supposed to work well with other scripts), these properties will be iterated over as well; inherited properties can be excluded by checking `hasOwnProperty()`, but that won't help you with properties set in the array object itself
- `for..in` isn't guaranteed to preserve element ordering
- it's slow because you have to walk all properties of the array object and its whole prototype chain and will still only get the property's name, ie to get the value, an additional lookup will be required

Answer (score 61):

Because for...in enumerates through the object that holds the array, not the array itself. If I add a function to the arrays prototype chain, that will also be included. I.e.

```js
Array.prototype.myOwnFunction = function() { alert(this); }
a = new Array();
a[0] = 'foo';
a[1] = 'bar';
for (var x in a) {
    document.write(x + ' = ' + a[x]);
}
```

This will write:

```
0 = foo
1 = bar
myOwnFunction = function() { alert(this); }
```

And since you can never be sure that nothing will be added to the prototype chain just use a for loop to enumerate the array:

```js
for (var i=0,x=a.length; i<x; i++) {
    document.write(i + ' = ' + a[i]);
}
```

This will write:

```
0 = foo
1 = bar
```

Comment: So a better statement in this case is: "Don't use for-in on arrays because it will include anything you add to the prototype"?

Answer (score 58):

As of 2016 (ES6) we may use `for…of` for array iteration, as John Slegers already noticed.

I would just like to add this simple demonstration code, to make things clearer:

```
Array.prototype.foo = 1;
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "xyz";

console.log("for...of:");
var count = 0;
for (var item of arr) {
    console.log(count + ":", item);
    count++;
    }

console.log("for...in:");
count = 0;
for (var item in arr) {
    console.log(count + ":", item);
    count++;
    }
```

The console shows:

```
for...of:

0: undefined
1: undefined
2: undefined
3: undefined
4: undefined
5: xyz

for...in:

0: 5
1: foo
```

In other words:

- `for...of` counts from 0 to 5, and also ignores `Array.prototype.foo`. It shows array **values**.
- `for...in` lists only the `5`, ignoring undefined array indexes, but adding `foo`. It shows array **property names**.

Answer (score 46):

Short answer: It's just not worth it.

---

Longer answer: It's just not worth it, even if sequential element order and optimal performance aren't required.

---

Long answer: It's just not worth it...

- Using `for (var property in array)` will cause `array` to be iterated over as an *object*, traversing the object prototype chain and ultimately performing slower than an index-based `for` loop.
- `for (... in ...)` is not guaranteed to return the object properties in sequential order, as one might expect.
- Using `hasOwnProperty()` and `!isNaN()` checks to filter the object properties is an additional overhead causing it to perform even slower and negates the key reason for using it in the first place, i.e. because of the more concise format.

For these reasons an acceptable trade-off between performance and convenience doesn't even exist.  There's really no benefit unless the intent is to handle the array as an *object* and perform operations on the object properties of the array.

Answer (score 41):

In isolation, there is nothing wrong with using for-in on arrays. For-in iterates over the property names of an object, and in the case of an "out-of-the-box" array, the properties corresponds to the array indexes. (The built-in propertes like `length`, `toString` and so on are not included in the iteration.)

However, if your code (or the framework you are using) add custom properties to arrays or to the array prototype, then these properties will be included in the iteration, which is probably not what you want.

Some  JS frameworks, like Prototype modifies the Array prototype. Other frameworks like JQuery doesn't, so with JQuery you can safely use for-in.

If you are in doubt, you probably shouldn't use for-in.

An alternative way of iterating through an array is using a for-loop:

```
for (var ix=0;ix<arr.length;ix++) alert(ix);
```

However, this have a different issue. The issue is that a JavaScript array can have "holes". If you define `arr` as:

```
var arr = ["hello"];
arr[100] = "goodbye";
```

Then the array have two items, but a length of 101. Using for-in will yield two indexes, while the for-loop will yield 101 indexes, where the 99 has a value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the reasons given in other answers, you may not want to use the "for...in" structure if you need to do math with the counter variable because the loop iterates through the names of the object's properties and so the variable is a string.

For example,

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    document.write(i + ', ' + typeof i + ', ' + i+1);
}
```

will write

```
0, number, 1
1, number, 2
...
```

whereas,

```
for (var ii in a) {
    document.write(i + ', ' + typeof i + ', ' + i+1);
}
```

will write

```
0, string, 01
1, string, 11
...
```

Of course, this can easily be overcome by including

```
ii = parseInt(ii);
```

in the loop, but the first structure is more direct.

Comment: You can use prefix `+` instead of `parseInt` unless you really need integer or ignore invalid characters.

Comment: Also, using `parseInt()` is not recommended. Try `parseInt("025");` and it *will* fail.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - you can definitely use `parseInt`. The issue is if you don't include the radix, older browsers might try to interpret the number (thus 025 becomes octal). This was fixed in ECMAScript 5 but it still happens for numbers starting with "0x" (it interprets the number as hex). To be on the safe side, use the radix to specify the number like so `parseInt("025", 10)` - that specifies base 10.

Answer (score 23):

Aside from the fact that `for`...`in` loops over all enumerable properties (which is *not* the same as "all array elements"!), see http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf, section 12.6.4 (5th edition) or 13.7.5.15 (7th edition):

> The mechanics and **order** of enumerating the properties ... **is not specified**...

(Emphasis mine.)

That means if a browser wanted to, it could go through the properties in the order in which they were inserted.  Or in numerical order.  Or in lexical order (where "30" comes before "4"!  Keep in mind all object keys -- and thus, all array indexes -- are actually strings, so that makes total sense).  It could go through them by bucket, if it implemented objects as hash tables.  Or take any of that and add "backwards".  A browser could even iterate *randomly* and be ECMA-262 compliant, as long as it visited each property exactly once.

In practice, most browsers currently like to iterate in roughly the same order.  But there's nothing saying they have to.  That's implementation specific, and could change at any time if another way was found to be far more efficient.

Either way, `for`...`in` carries with it no connotation of order.  If you care about order, be explicit about it and use a regular `for` loop with an index.

Answer (score 19):

Mainly two reasons:

**One**

Like others have said, You might get keys which aren't in your array or that are inherited from the prototype. So if, let's say, a library adds a property to the Array or Object prototypes:

```
Array.prototype.someProperty = true
```

You'll get it as part of every array:

```
for(var item in [1,2,3]){
  console.log(item) // will log 1,2,3 but also "someProperty"
}
```

you could solve this with the hasOwnProperty method:

```
var ary = [1,2,3];
for(var item in ary){
   if(ary.hasOwnProperty(item)){
      console.log(item) // will log only 1,2,3
   }
}
```

but this is true for iterating over any object with a for-in loop.

**Two**

Usually the order of the items in an array is important, but the for-in loop won't necessarily iterate in the right order, that's because it treats the array as an object, which is the way it is implemented in JS, and not as an array.
This seems like a small thing, but it can really screw up applications and is hard to debug.

Comment: `Object.keys(a).forEach( function(item) { console.log(item) } )`
iterate over an array of own property keys, not those inherited from prototype.

Comment: True, but like the for-in loop, it won't necessarily be in the right index order. Also, it won't work on older browsers not supporting ES5.

Comment: You can teach those browsers `array.forEach` by inserting certain code in your scripts. See Polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Of course, but then you are manipulating the prototype, and that is not always a good idea...and still, you have the issue of the order...

Answer (score 17):

I don't think I have much to add to eg. [Triptych's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea/500531#500531) or [CMS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea/4261096#4261096) on why using `for...in` should be avoided in some cases.

I do, however, would like to add that **in modern browsers** there is an alternative to `for...in` that can be used in those cases where `for...in` can't be used. That alternative is [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) :

```
for (var item of items) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

---

#### Note :

Unfortunately, no version of Internet Explorer supports `for...of` ([Edge 12+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge) does), so you'll have to wait a bit longer until you can use it in your client side production code. However, it should be safe to use in your server side JS code (if you use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)).

Answer (score 16):

Because it enumerates through object fields, not indexes. You can get value with index "length" and I doubt you want this.

Comment: In firefox 3 you could also use either arr.forEach or for(var [i, v] in Iterator(arr)) {} but neither of those works in IE, although you can write forEach method yourself.

Comment: This answer is wrong. "lenght" will not be included in for-in iteration. It is only properties you add yourself which is included.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with `for ... in ...` — and this only becomes a problem when a programmer doesn't really understand the language; it's not really a bug or anything — is that it iterates over *all* members of an object (well, all *enumerable* members, but that's a detail for now).  When you want to iterate over *just* the indexed properties of an array, the only guaranteed way to keep things semantically consistent is to use an integer index (that is, a `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)` style loop).

Any object can have arbitrary properties associated with it. There would be nothing terrible about loading additional properties onto an array instance, in particular. Code that wants to see *only* indexed array-like properties therefore *must* stick to an integer index. Code that is fully aware of what `for ... in` does and really *need* to see all properties, well then that's ok too.

Comment: Nice explanation Pointy. Just curious.  If I had an array that was inside an object under multiply properties and did `for in`, as compared to a regular for loop, those arrays would get iterated over? (which would in essence, slow performance, right?)

Comment: @NiCkNewman well the object you reference after `in` in a `for ... in` loop will just

Comment: I see. Just curious because I have objects and arrays inside my main game object and was wondering if for inning that would be more painful then simply a regular for loop on the indexes.

Comment: @NiCkNewman well the theme of this whole question is that you just should not use `for ... in` on arrays; there are many good reasons not to. It's no so much a performance issue as a "make sure it doesn't break" issue.

Comment: Well, my objects are stored in an array technically, that's why I was worried, something like: `[{a:'hey',b:'hi'},{a:'hey',b:'hi'}]`, but yea, I understand.

Answer (score 12):

**TL&DR:** Using the `for in` loop in arrays is not evil, in fact quite the opposite.

I think the `for in` loop is a gem of JS if used *correctly* in arrays. You are expected to have full control over your software and know what you are doing. Let's see the mentioned drawbacks and disprove them one by one.

1. **It loops through inherited properties as well:** First of all any extensions to the `Array.prototype` should have been done by using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and their `enumerable` descriptor should be set to `false`. Any library not doing so should not be used at all.
2. **Properties those you add to the inheritance chain later get counted:** When doing array sub-classing by `Object.setPrototypeOf` or by Class `extend`. You should again use `Object.defineProperty()` which by default sets the `writable`, `enumerable` and `configurable` property descriptors to `false`. Lets see an array sub-classing example here...

```js
function Stack(...a){
  var stack = new Array(...a);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(stack, Stack.prototype);
  return stack;
}
Stack.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);                                 // now stack has full access to array methods.
Object.defineProperty(Stack.prototype,"constructor",{value:Stack});               // now Stack is a proper constructor
Object.defineProperty(Stack.prototype,"peak",{value: function(){                  // add Stack "only" methods to the Stack.prototype.
                                                       return this[this.length-1];
                                                     }
                                             });
var s = new Stack(1,2,3,4,1);
console.log(s.peak());
s[s.length] = 7;
console.log("length:",s.length);
s.push(42);
console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
console.log("length:",s.length);

for(var i in s) console.log(s[i]);
```

So you see.. `for in` loop is now safe since you cared about your code.

3. **The `for in` loop is slow:** Hell no. It's by far the fastest method of iteration if you are looping over sparse arrays which are needed time to time. This is one of the most important performance tricks that one should know. Let's see an example. We will loop over a sparse array.

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = "zero";
a[10000000] = "ten million";
console.time("for loop on array a:");
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] && console.log(a[i]);
console.timeEnd("for loop on array a:");
console.time("for in loop on array a:");
for(var i in a) a[i] && console.log(a[i]);
console.timeEnd("for in loop on array a:");
```

Answer (score 10):

Also, due to semantics, the way `for, in` treats arrays (i.e. the same as any other JavaScript object) is not aligned with other popular languages.

```
// C#
char[] a = new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C'};
foreach (char x in a) System.Console.Write(x); //Output: "ABC"

// Java
char[] a = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
for (char x : a) System.out.print(x);          //Output: "ABC"

// PHP
$a = array('A', 'B', 'C');
foreach ($a as $x) echo $x;                    //Output: "ABC"

// JavaScript
var a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
for (var x in a) document.write(x);            //Output: "012"
```

Comment: The argument here is that being different is a bad thing?

Comment: @LeeGoddard not at all, just pointing out that _usually_ one uses for...in to iterate the "values", not the "keys". JS behavior is not a bad thing, it just may be counterintuitive for many developers coming from other popular programming languages, who may not understand the error at first and then prefer not to use for...in in this context. That's all the answer points out, it adds up as a con but of course that's debatable.

Comment: @matpoop - Vive la différence! Greets from the former-Communist east.

Answer (score 10):

Here are the reasons why this is (usually) a bad practice:

1. `for...in` loops iterate over all their own enumerable properties **and** the enumerable properties of their prototype(s). Usually in an array iteration we only want to iterate over the array itself. And even though you yourself may not add anything to the array, your libraries or framework might add something.

**Example**:

```js
Array.prototype.hithere = 'hithere';

var array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let el in array){
    // the hithere property will also be iterated over
    console.log(el);
}
```

2. `for...in` loops **do not guarantee a specific iteration order**. Although is order is usually seen in most modern browsers these days, there is still no 100% guarantee.
3. `for...in` loops ignore `undefined` array elements, i.e. array elements which not have been assigned yet.

**Example:**:

```js
const arr = []; 
arr[3] = 'foo';   // resize the array to 4
arr[4] = undefined; // add another element with value undefined to it

// iterate over the array, a for loop does show the undefined elements
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}

console.log('\n');

// for in does ignore the undefined elements
for (let el in arr) {
    console.log(arr[el]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `for`/`in` works with two types of variables: hashtables (associative arrays) and array (non-associative).

JavaScript will automatically determine the way its passes through the items. So if you know that your array is really non-associative you can use `for (var i=0; i<=arrayLen; i++)`, and skip the auto-detection iteration.

But in my opinion, it's better to use `for`/`in`, the process required for that auto-detection is very small.

A real answer for this will depend on how the browser parsers/interpret the JavaScript code. It can change between browsers.

I can't think of other purposes to not using `for`/`in`;

```
//Non-associative
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i in arr)
   alert(arr[i]);

//Associative
var arr = {
   item1 : 'a',
   item2 : 'b',
   item3 : 'c'
};

for (var i in arr)
   alert(arr[i]);
```

Comment: `for ... in` works with objects. There's no such thing as auto-detection.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other problems, the "for..in" syntax is probably slower, because the index is a string, not an integer.

```
var a = ["a"]
for (var i in a)
    alert(typeof i)  // 'string'
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    alert(typeof i)  // 'number'
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter a whole lot.  Array elements are properties of an Array-based or Array-like object, and all object properties have string keys.  Unless your JS engine somehow optimizes it, even if you used a number it'd end up being turned into a string for the lookup.

Comment: Regardless of any performance issues, if you are new to JavaScript, use `var i in a` and expect the index to be an integer, then doing something like `a[i+offset] = <value>` will be putting values in completely the wrong places. ("1" + 1 == "11").

Answer (score 8):

An important aspect is that `for...in` only iterates over properties contained in an object which have their **enumerable** *property attribute* set to true. So if one attempts to iterate over an object using `for...in` then arbitrary properties may be missed if their enumerable property attribute is false. It is quite possible to alter the enumerable property attribute for normal Array objects so that certain elements are not enumerated. Though in general the property attributes tend to apply to function properties within an object.

One can check the value of a properties' enumerable property attribute by:

```
myobject.propertyIsEnumerable('myproperty')
```

Or to obtain all four property attributes:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myobject,'myproperty')
```

This is a feature available in ECMAScript 5 - in earlier versions it was not possible to alter the value of the enumerable property attribute (it was always set to true).

Answer (score 7):

Because it will iterate over properties belonging to objects up the prototype chain if you're not careful.

You can use `for.. in`, just be sure to check each property with [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: Not enough - it's perfectly OK to add arbitrary named properties to array instances, and those will test `true` from `hasOwnProperty()` checks.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've never been silly enough to do that to an Array myself, so I haven't considered that!

Comment: @Pointy I haven't tested this, but perhaps this can be overcome by using an `isNaN` check on each property name.

Comment: @Wynand interesting idea; however I don't really see why it's worth the trouble when iterating with a simple numeric index is so easy.

Comment: @WynandB sorry for the bump, but I feel a correction is in order: `isNaN` is for checking whether a variable is the special value NaN or not, it cannot be used to check for 'things other than numbers' (you can go with a regular typeof for that).

Answer (score 6):

It's not *necessarily* bad (based on what you're doing), but in the case of arrays, if something has been added to `Array.prototype`, then you're going to get strange results.  Where you'd expect this loop to run three times:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
for (var key in arr) { ... }
```

If a function called `helpfulUtilityMethod` has been added to `Array`'s `prototype`, then your loop would end up running four times: `key` would be `0`, `1`, `2`, and `helpfulUtilityMethod`.  If you were only expecting integers, oops.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `for(var x in y)` only on property lists, not on objects (as explained above).

Comment: Just a note about SO - there is no 'above' because comments change order on the page all the time. So, we don't really know which comment you mean. It's good to say "in x person's comment" for this reason.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `for...in` loop for an array is not wrong, although I can guess why someone told you that:

1.) There is already a higher order function, or method, that has that purpose for an array, but has more functionality and leaner syntax, called 'forEach': `Array.prototype.forEach(function(element, index, array) {} );`

2.) Arrays always have a length, but `for...in` and `forEach` do not execute a function for any value that is `'undefined'`, only for the indexes that have a value defined. So if you only assign one value, these loops will only execute a function once, but since an array is enumerated, it will always have a length up to the highest index that has a defined value, but that length could go unnoticed when using these loops.

3.) The standard for loop will execute a function as many times as you define in the parameters, and since an array is numbered, it makes more sense to define how many times you want to execute a function. Unlike the other loops, the for loop can then execute a function for every index in the array, whether the value is defined or not.

In essence, you can use any loop, but you should remember exactly how they work. Understand the conditions upon which the different loops reiterate, their separate functionalities, and realize they will be more or less appropriate for differing scenarios.

Also, it may be considered a better practice to use the `forEach` method than the `for...in` loop in general, because it is easier to write and has more functionality, so you may want to get in the habit of only using this method and standard for, but your call.

See below that the first two loops only execute the console.log statements once, while the standard for loop executes the function as many times as specified, in this case, array.length = 6.

```
var arr = [];
arr[5] = 'F';

for (var index in arr) {
console.log(index);
console.log(arr[index]);
console.log(arr)
}
// 5
// 'F'
// => (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

arr.forEach(function(element, index, arr) {
console.log(index);
console.log(element);
console.log(arr);
});
// 5
// 'F'
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
console.log(index);
console.log(arr[index]);
console.log(arr);
};
// 0
// undefined
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

// 1
// undefined
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

// 2
// undefined
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

// 3
// undefined
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

// 4
// undefined
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]

// 5
// 'F'
// => Array (6) [undefined x 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

A for...in loop always enumerates the keys.
Objects properties keys are always String, even the indexed properties of an array :

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var total = 0
for (elem in myArray) {
  total += elem
}
console.log(total); // 00123
```

Answer (score 2):

**for...in** is useful when working on an object in JavaScript, but not for an Array, but still we can not say it's a wrong way, but it's not recommended, look at this example below using **for...in** loop:

```
let txt = "";
const person = {fname:"Alireza", lname:"Dezfoolian", age:35}; 
for (const x in person) {
    txt += person[x] + " ";
}
console.log(txt); //Alireza Dezfoolian 35
```

OK, let's do it with **Array** now:

```
let txt = "";
const person = ["Alireza", "Dezfoolian", 35]; 
for (const x in person) {
   txt += person[x] + " ";
}
console.log(txt); //Alireza Dezfoolian 35
```

As you see the result the same...

But let's try something, let's prototype something to **Array**...

```
Array.prototype.someoneelse = "someoneelse";
```

Now we create a new Array();

```
let txt = "";
const arr = new Array();
arr[0] = 'Alireza';
arr[1] = 'Dezfoolian';
arr[2] = 35;
for(x in arr) {
 txt += arr[x] + " ";
}
console.log(txt); //Alireza Dezfoolian 35 someoneelse
```

You see the **someoneelse**!!!... We actually looping through new Array object in this case!

So that's one of the reasons why we need to use **for..in** carefully, but it's not always the case...

Answer (score 2):

> Since JavaScript elements are saved as standard object properties, it
>   is not advisable to iterate through JavaScript arrays using for...in
>   loops because normal elements and all enumerable properties will be
>   listed.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections

Answer (score 1):

although not specifically addressed by this question, I would add that there's a very good reason not to ever use for...in with a `NodeList` (as one would obtain from a `querySelectorAll` call, as it doesn't see the returned elements at all, instead iterating only over the NodeList properties.

in the case of a single result, I got:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
nodes
▶ NodeList [a._19eb]
for (node in nodes) {console.log(node)};
VM505:1 0
VM505:1 length
VM505:1 item
VM505:1 entries
VM505:1 forEach
VM505:1 keys
VM505:1 values
```

which explained why my `for (node in nodes) node.href = newLink;` was failing.

Answer (score 0):

for in loop converts the indices to string when traversing through an array.
For example, In the below code, in the second loop where initialising j with i+1, i is the index but in a string ("0", "1" etc) and number + string in js is a string. if js encounters "0" + 1 it will return "01".

```js
var maxProfit = function(prices) {
  let maxProfit = 0;
  for (let i in prices) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < prices.length; j++) {
      console.log(prices[j] - prices[i], "i,j", i, j, typeof i, typeof j);
      if ((prices[j] - prices[i]) > maxProfit) maxProfit = (prices[j] - prices[i]);
    }
  }
  return maxProfit;
};

maxProfit([7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4]);
```