# Select All/Deselect All checkboxes in a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, checkbox

I've looked at [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=2151) which seems to have no effect on my code.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888173/select-all-checkboxes) which seems to only affect the first checkbox, but doesn't uncheck the checkbox when i click it again anyway....
I've also seen some other ways of doing it that I'm not certain are entirely Rails-esque (or whatever the term should be).

So, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is my view:

```
<%= render 'admin/distributions/head' %>
<% title 'Workflow' %>


<%= form_for @search, :url => url_for(:controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]), :html => {id => "distribution_workflow",:method => :get} do |f| %>

  <div class="opportunity-block yellow">

    <div class="form-block mrl mbm">
      <%= f.label :created_at_gt, "Created at >" %>
      <%= f.text_field :created_at_gt, :class => "js-db-date-picker" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-block mrl mbm">
      <%= f.label :created_at_lte, "Created at <=" %>
      <%= f.text_field :created_at_lte, :class => "js-db-date-picker" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-block mrl mbm mtm">
      <%= f.label :status_equal, "Status" %>
      <%= f.select :status_equal, %w(delivered no_success already_registered qa_complete success follow_up), :include_blank => " " %>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Apply Filter', :class => "input-button dark unit-right mrl" %>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
<% end  %>


<%= form_tag edit_multiple_admin_distributions_workflows_path , :id => "workflow_form" do %>
<%= submit_tag "Edit Selected" %>
  <table class="standard-grid"> 
    <tr> 
      <th class="first"> </th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Resume URL</th>
      <th>Partner</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    <% @report.each do |distribution| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "distribution_ids[]", distribution.id %></td>
        <td>
          <%= distribution.owner.id %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=link_to distribution.owner.full_name, "mailto:#{distribution.owner.email}" %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href=<% UrlService.download_blob_url(distribution.resume) %>>Resume URL</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=link_to distribution.matching_profile.partner.title,  "mailto:#{distribution.matching_profile.partner.email}" %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= distribution.status %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= distribution.assignee_id ? User.find(distribution.assignee_id).full_name : " " %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= distribution.comments %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this question has to do with Rails.  This is typically a Javascript question which would require you posting the rendered HTML and retagging the question.

Comment: should i post the all the html of the entire page? Or is the html for the form enough?

Comment: I tried to answer your question as best as I could below.  For future reference, if it involves changing the page after the page is rendered, it's probably Javascript (unless you are rendering a `.js.erb` file or something like that)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a working example for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/wYPWL/

HTML example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="selectAll"> Select / Deselect All<br/><br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
       $(':checkbox').each(function() {
           this.checked = true;                        
       });
   } else {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
           this.checked = false;                        
       });
   } 
});
```

This will work regardless of what your checkboxes are named.  If you really wanted to target only your checkboxes shown in your code above, you can replace `$(':checkbox')` with `$('input[id^="distribution_ids"]')` which is jQuery's way of targeting input elements that have an ID that starts with **distribution_ids**

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to rails, new to web-dev and REALLY new to javascript. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad to help, I figured you were new to the frontend side of things :)  jQuery is your friend, believe me.  If you don't already have it installed in your rails project, see this link:  https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: @iWasRobbed : Sorry dude I have found and issue in your Answer... Try to Select All then uncheck any one option(like Bar1, Bar2, Bar3).. "SElect ALl" must be unchecked... Check my Answer..

Answer (score 2):

If using jquery, you can use the following (coffeeScript):

```
if (this.checked)
  $(':checkbox').each ->
    $(this).prop('checked', true)                     
else
  $(':checkbox').each ->
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
```

I found an issue trying to set this.checked = false - not really sure what was happening, but the above code worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an issue with **[iWasRobbed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585572/select-all-deselect-all-checkboxes-in-a-page/24632888#answer-8585749)**'s Answer that if `Select All` is checked and then if you unchecked any one option like (`Bar1`, `Bar2`, `Bar3`) then `Select All` must be unchecked...

Here is Solution..

***HTML Code***

```
<input id="campaign_range_ids_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="campaign[range_ids][]"> India
<input id="campaign_range_ids_2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="campaign[range_ids][]"> London
<input id="campaign_range_ids_3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="campaign[range_ids][]"> USA
<input id="campaign_range_ids_4" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" name="campaign[range_ids][]"> All
```

***JavaScript Code:***

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', true);

    } else {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', false);
    }

});

$('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        } else {
            $('#campaign_range_ids_4').prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/eKHFb/14/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to select-all for multiple separate lists on the same page

```
$("input[data-select-all]").on("click", function() {
    let $checkboxes = $("input[data-"+$(this).data("select-all")+"]");
    if (this.checked) {
        $checkboxes.each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    } else {
        $checkboxes.each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});


<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="select-all" value="1" title="Select all" data-select-all="select-all-target"></th>
    <th>Asset</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="asset_type_11" value="1" data-select-all-target="true"></span></td>
    <td>The name</td>
    <td>The description</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```