# Difference between "script type" and "script language" declarations

Tags: javascript

Are there any important differences between declaring `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` and `<script language="javascript"> </script>`?

(Note I'm not asking about these declarations vs. the blank "`<script>`" tag)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language

Comment: @j08691 nice find, voting to close as dup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Script tag: type or language (or omit both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `<script type="text/javascript">` or simply `<script>` (if omitted, the `type` is the same). Do not use `<script language="JavaScript">`; the `language` attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

The language attribute was used when `<script>` was introduced in HTML 3.2 and took a language name (such as `JavaScript`). The type attribute replaced it in HTML 4.0 (as everything describing non-HTML media started taking MIME types) and takes a MIME type (such as `text/javascript`). More recently it also supports the special value `module` for JavaScript modules (which support the `import` keyword).

Answer (score 2):

`<script language="javascript"> </script>` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

`<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` is the current (HTML4) way to do it.

If you have an HTML5 DOCTYPE, you can just do `<script> </script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Language is generally used to indicate the Javascript *version* that your script requires. Browsers that support the language attribute won't load or run the script if it doesn't support it. About the only use would be if you had critical Javascript functions where you needed workarounds for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<script language="JavaScript">` not passes validation HTML 4.01. Type attribute is required.