# What's wrong with this JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a JavaScript newbie, just doing a little script so that I can rotate an image + link every few days. I'm 90% sure my error is in the bottom line of code - seems to be something to do with the way quotes are used (which is confusing me a lot).

Correct code + explanation of where and why to use quotes would be much appreciated!

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- Begin
today = new Date();
date = today.getDate();
date = date - date%9;
date = date/9;
date = date%3;

arday = new Array("image 1", "image 2", "image 3");

linkday = new Array("link 1", "link 2", "link 3");

document.write("<a href= '" + linkday[date] + target="_blank" ><img src='" + arday[date] "'/> </a>");
// End -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What *is* wrong with it? Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @PenchoIlchev It should actually not be. This is a legacy feature (that should actually *be removed*). `//<!--` would make the feature "not work correctly" in the old-old-old-browsers (like Netscape 3?) where it was intended to work.

Comment: @PenchoIlchev Sure, but useless comments are fun ;-)

Comment: @everyone - hah, looks like my code is pretty crude then - shows how unhelpful copy/pasting code from forums and website tutorials can be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `language` attribute is ignored by browsers, remove it. Even the `type` attribute can be omitted.
- If you are not parsing this page as XML, remove the `<!-- -->`
- Use array literals instead of `new Array()`
- Use `var` when declaring variables
- Chain variable declarations using commas. Notice one `var` and a series of variable declarations.
- Although single quotes are accepted, in HTML, use double quotes `""` for attribute values.
- To avoid escaping double quotes, wrap strings in single quotes.
- There shall be no spaces between the opening bracket `<` and the tag name.
- There shall be no spaces between the attribute name, the equal sign and the opening quote.

[Here's a cleaned code](http://jsfiddle.net/j2B6U/1/):

```
<script>
    var today = new Date(),
        date = today.getDate(),
        arday = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"],
        linkday = ["link 1", "link 2", "link 3"];

    date = date - date % 9;
    date = date / 9;
    date = date % 3;

    document.write('<a href="' + linkday[date] + '" target="_blank" ><img src="' + arday[date] + '" / ></a>');​
</script>
```

Comment: @Jordan updated the answer, and added a demo. I missed a small detail.

Comment: Also, the img tag needs an alt attribute. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape some quotes and add some other ones in your `document.write` statement:

```
document.write("<a href='" + linkday[date] + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + arday[date] "' /></a>");
```

When you use variables, you should also use `var` to prevent them from automatically attaching to the global namespace. In this case, there is no visible difference, but there *would* be a difference if the above code was in a function. So the following variable assignments would be preferred:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate();
date = date - date % 9;
date /= 9;
date %= 3;

var arday = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"];
var linkday = ["link 1", "link 2", "link 3"];
```

By the way, the proper tag to use is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

[`language` has been deprecated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language) The `type` attribute *can* be omitted in HTML5, however, if that is the doctype that you are using.

Also, the comments

```
<!-- Begin
...
// End -->
```

can be removed, as they don't serve much of a purpose in modern-day browsers, and actually *does* comment out the script if a browser is fully following XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Go from the correct string and add things in

```
<a href="" target="_blank" ><img src=""/></a>
```

Wrap it in single quotes since the string above is using double quotes.

```
'<a href="" target="_blank" ><img src=""/></a>'
```

Add the first variable reference

```
'<a href="' + linkday[date] + '" target="_blank" ><img src=""/></a>'
```

Add the second variable

```
'<a href="' + linkday[date] + '" target="_blank" ><img src="' + arday[date] + '"/></a>'
```

wrap it in the document.write

```
document.write('<a href="' + linkday[date] + '" target="_blank" ><img src="' + arday[date] + '"/></a>');
```