# I write this code sample code to hide 2 rows but it did not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide two rows, `<tr><td>line 1</td></tr>` and `<tr><td>line 2</td></tr>`, by wrapping them in a div with `display:none` set, but these rows are not hidden. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
      text.innerHTML = "Show";
    } else {
      ele.style.display = "block";
      text.innerHTML = "Hide";
    }
  } 
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <div id="toggleText" style="display: none;">
    <tr><td>line 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>line 2</td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we see your actual code please ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: if you're going to use a script tag you should either use the `type` attribute for files that are not `HTML5` or optionally no tag for files that are `HTML5`. Both will work but `type="text/javascript"` adheres to the latest standards for non `HTML5` pages. See this [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language)...

Comment: @War10ck - That comment would have been better phrased as an edit ...

Comment: @d-Pixie I'm not sure I follow you. I shouldn't be editing something like that in the op's question. That would change the context of the original question. It's up to the op to make that change if and when he/she feels it is appropriate. It was merely a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to put a div inside of a table it needs to live inside of a table cell, meaning inside of a td. Notice I am selecting the two divs by class name since id is intended to be unique.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
 function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele[0].style.display == "block") {
        ele[0].style.display = "none";
        ele[1].style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show";
    }
    else {
        ele[0].style.display = "block";
        ele[1].style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide";
    }
} 
</script>
<table>

    <tr><td>
    <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show</a>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><div class="toggleText">line 1</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="toggleText">line 2</div></td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML markup is invalid, You can not have a div as a child element in a table!

Comment: How can i hide those 2 rows? So that when i click Show, it will show these two rows?

Comment: wrap them in a tbody element.