# knockout mapping from JSON not show data on UI

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

```
<script language="javascript">
    var user = {"firstName":"Test","lastName":"Test Last"};
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(user);  
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);  
</script>

<input type="text" id="txtFName" data-bind="value: firstName" class="input-small" >
<input type="text" id="txtLName" data-bind="value: lastName" class="input-small">
```

But by some reason knockout doesn't show result on UI.
What is can be ?

Comment: Put the scipt tag under your inputs... and you should use `type="text/javascript"` instead of `language="Javascript"` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both

Comment: Yes it is working thanks. What is the issue ? knockout with out mapping working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like nemesv says, you should use the following in your script block:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

Are you sure you have the correct references to knockout and knockout mapping? I created a jsfiddle based on your code which works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/CUNWn/