# language="javascript" vs. type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, html

For adding JavaScript to HTML, I have seen people use

```
<script language=javascript>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

It doesn’t seem like whether the script is embedded or external influences this decision.

Which one is preferred and why?

Comment: the attribute itself is optional, and really not necessary anymore. you can just use `<script>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Script tag: type or language (or omit both)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Script tag: type or language (or omit both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`<script language="javascript">` was used in *very* old browsers, and is deprecated.

`<script type="text/javascript">` is the HTML 4 standard.

In HTML 5, the `type` parameter is optional (`text/javascript` is the default), so you can just do `<script>`.

As a neat hack, if you put an invalid `type`, the script won't be ran, but you can still read the data in JavaScript.  Some template libraries do this.

Comment: Yahoo uses a mix of <script language="javascript"> and <script type="text/javascript"> :)

Comment: @Foo: You can still use deprecated features, and mix standards.  *It's not good practice*, and isn't valid HTML, but most browsers will run it anyway.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Without some solid source on the matter I would not trust every browser out there to refrain from trying to run a script block just because it has a weird type attribute set. And even if it does work all across the board I still think "horrendous" would be a better adjective than "neat" ;-)

Comment: @eBusiness: Fair enough.  I've just seen it done, and assumed it was fine.  I can check to see what the spec says ^_^

Comment: Today, the recommended way to embed schema.org metadata in a web page is by embedding a JSON fragment in a script tag with `type="application/ld+json"`. So I guess it is save to say we can now trust browsers not to run it, as it is embedded this way on millions of sites.

Answer (score 8):

The [`language` attribute is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script). Use `type` only. You don't need to specify `type` in HTML5, it's javascript per default.

Comment: In HTML 5, you don't even need `type`!  Just `<script>` :-)

Comment: @AgustinMeriles that's valid in HMTL. Just not in XHTML.

Comment: @Christoph - unless this person is using XML, i think they're safe.

Comment: If they are using a browser, they are safe. Just stick your XHTML doctype on your horribly invalid HTML and it will still work more or less the same. Browsers might switch to some non-standards mode, but I think even that has been more or less phased out already. Browsers always only really used one parser/rendering engine anyway, this just supported some 'standards mode /quirks mode' toggle and that was it. XHTML just never really made it past the W3C validator.