# All users have one profile

Tags: php, database, registration, profile

I want to make my small social network, I made the database, registration, login and profile pages, it works properly but I don't know how to make the users not go to the same profile page when they click on profile, but to have their own profile, more precisely their profile link. I put that pictures can be posted but when I post pictures from different user accounts, they all go to one profile.

**registration.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="registration.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require('db.php');
    // When form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
        // removes backslashes
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        //escapes special characters in a string
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
        $email    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
        $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
        $create_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query    = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, create_datetime)
                     VALUES ('$username', '" . md5($password) . "', '$email', '$create_datetime')";
        $result   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if ($result) {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></p>
                  </div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Required fields are missing.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='registration.php'>registration</a> again.</p>
                  </div>";
        }
    } else {
?>
<script language="javascript">
                document.location.href='<?php echo SERVER_URL;?>user/';
                </script>

<body class="align">
    

  <div class="grid">

    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" name="login" class="form login">

      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="login__username"><svg class="icon">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
          </svg><span class="hidden">Username</span></label>
        <input autocomplete="username" id="login__username" type="text" name="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="login__username"><svg class="icon">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
          </svg><span class="hidden">Email</span></label>
        <input autocomplete="username" id="login__username" type="text" name="email" class="form__input" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="login__password"><svg class="icon">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-lock"></use>
          </svg><span class="hidden">Password</span></label>
        <input id="login__password" type="password" name="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

      <div class="form__field">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="submit" class="login-button">
      </div>

    </form>

    <p class="text--center">Already member? <a href="https://raakado.000webhostapp.com/login">Log in</a> <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
      </svg></p>

  </div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icons">
    <symbol id="icon-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M1600 960q0 54-37 91l-651 651q-39 37-91 37-51 0-90-37l-75-75q-38-38-38-91t38-91l293-293H245q-52 0-84.5-37.5T128 1024V896q0-53 32.5-90.5T245 768h704L656 474q-38-36-38-90t38-90l75-75q38-38 90-38 53 0 91 38l651 651q37 35 37 90z" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-lock" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M640 768h512V576q0-106-75-181t-181-75-181 75-75 181v192zm832 96v576q0 40-28 68t-68 28H416q-40 0-68-28t-28-68V864q0-40 28-68t68-28h32V576q0-184 132-316t316-132 316 132 132 316v192h32q40 0 68 28t28 68z" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-user" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M1600 1405q0 120-73 189.5t-194 69.5H459q-121 0-194-69.5T192 1405q0-53 3.5-103.5t14-109T236 1084t43-97.5 62-81 85.5-53.5T538 832q9 0 42 21.5t74.5 48 108 48T896 971t133.5-21.5 108-48 74.5-48 42-21.5q61 0 111.5 20t85.5 53.5 62 81 43 97.5 26.5 108.5 14 109 3.5 103.5zm-320-893q0 159-112.5 271.5T896 896 624.5 783.5 512 512t112.5-271.5T896 128t271.5 112.5T1280 512z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login__password");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>


<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('db.php');
    // When form submitted, check and create user session.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);    // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
        // Check user is exist in the database
        $query    = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
                     AND password='" . md5($password) . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Redirect to user dashboard page
            header("Location: https://raakado.000webhostapp.com");
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Incorrect Username/password.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a> again.</p>
                  </div>";
        }
    } else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"/>
</head>
<body class="align">
    

  <div class="grid">

    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" name="login" class="form login">

      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="login__username"><svg class="icon">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
          </svg><span class="hidden">Username</span></label>
        <input autocomplete="username" id="login__username" type="text" name="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="login__password"><svg class="icon">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-lock"></use>
          </svg><span class="hidden">Password</span></label>
        <input id="login__password" type="password" name="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

      <div class="form__field">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="login-button">
      </div>

    </form>

    <p class="text--center">Not a member? <a href="https://raakado.000webhostapp.com/registration">Sign up now</a> <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
      </svg></p>

  </div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icons">
    <symbol id="icon-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M1600 960q0 54-37 91l-651 651q-39 37-91 37-51 0-90-37l-75-75q-38-38-38-91t38-91l293-293H245q-52 0-84.5-37.5T128 1024V896q0-53 32.5-90.5T245 768h704L656 474q-38-36-38-90t38-90l75-75q38-38 90-38 53 0 91 38l651 651q37 35 37 90z" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-lock" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M640 768h512V576q0-106-75-181t-181-75-181 75-75 181v192zm832 96v576q0 40-28 68t-68 28H416q-40 0-68-28t-28-68V864q0-40 28-68t68-28h32V576q0-184 132-316t316-132 316 132 132 316v192h32q40 0 68 28t28 68z" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-user" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
      <path d="M1600 1405q0 120-73 189.5t-194 69.5H459q-121 0-194-69.5T192 1405q0-53 3.5-103.5t14-109T236 1084t43-97.5 62-81 85.5-53.5T538 832q9 0 42 21.5t74.5 48 108 48T896 971t133.5-21.5 108-48 74.5-48 42-21.5q61 0 111.5 20t85.5 53.5 62 81 43 97.5 26.5 108.5 14 109 3.5 103.5zm-320-893q0 159-112.5 271.5T896 896 624.5 783.5 512 512t112.5-271.5T896 128t271.5 112.5T1280 512z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login__password");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
    }
?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
  include 'auth_session.php';;
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id16563693_mmain1", "!Aleksajecar2006", "id16563693_main1");
  $results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users1");
  $users = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raakado.000webhostapp.com/style1.css">
  <title><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> - Profile</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

</head>
<body>
    
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="https://raakado.000webhostapp.com">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  
  <a style="float:right" href="form.php">Upload Image</a>
  
  <div style="float:right" class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
      <a href="https://raakado.000webhostapp.com/inbox">Inbox</a>
      <a id="shake" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
    
  </div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
    
    <div class="informations">
    <h1 align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1>
    <p align="center"><b>Followers: </b>0</p>
    <p align="center"><b>Following: </b>0</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>

    
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 offset-md-4" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <br>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
              <tr>
                <td> <img src="<?php echo 'images/' . $user['profile_image'] ?>" width="300" height="200" alt=""> </td>
                <td style="color:white;"> <?php echo $user['bio']; ?> </td>
                </div>
              </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to read the following, and pay specific attention to Minimal... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: use `/profile` for own, i.e it grabs id from session and use `/profile/1` or `/profile.php?id=1` to specifically set the id. Then query by id. A profile is no diff from any other dynamic page, you define a value and then you query the table based on the value, for uploading you obv, use the current users id, or look for some other flag like isAdmin

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: `language="javascript"` has been deprecated for years [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975831/2310830)

Comment: See the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36628423/2310830) and dont fiddle with the users password, mainly because its totally unnecessary