# PHP email validation function cannot echo JS alert?

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
       echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
       echo 'alert(Valid email)';   
       echo '</script>';
    } else { 
       echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
       echo 'alert(Not valid email)';   
       echo '</script>';     
    }
}
```

i'm trying to show an alert with the result but it's not working. however echo a text working but not JS alert.

why is that? is there another way to do that?

Comment: [`language="javascript"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975786/language-javascript-vs-type-text-javascript) is dead and gone

Comment: Missing quotes for the strings you want to alert? Wouldn't your browser console give a hint on that?

Comment: i.e. `echo 'alert("Valid email")'; `

Comment: yes missing quotes, it's working. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `'<script type="application/javascript">'`
instead of `'<script language="javascript">'`

yout script tag attribute is wrong and also you use alert function wrong.
change `alert(Valid email)` to `alert("Valid email")` and
change `alert(Not valid email)` to `alert("Not valid email")`.