# What is the proper jQuery Syntax for removing a class based upon a visitor's brand web browser?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, removeclass, navigator

I am wanting to remove a class from a specified ID if a visitor is using Internet Explorer (IE).

At first, I created a redirect for visitors using IE with the following JavaScript syntax, and it worked just fine:

```
<script language=javascript>
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/IE/i))) {
    document.location = "http://www.somepage.com/IE_page.html";
    }
</script>
```

But I want to take a different tack.  Rather than redirect to another page, I want the ability to remove (or add perhaps) class(es) to ID's.

What I created, but hasn't worked, was this:

```
<script language=javascript>
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/IE/i))) {
    $('#someIdHere').removeClass('someClassHere');
    }
</script>
```

I have the requisite jQuery link above this script.

What syntax am I missing with this jQuery statement?

Comment: `<script language=javascript>`? Why are you writing HTML 3.2 in 2013?

Comment: Browser sniffing is really out these days !

Comment: @adeneo I don't doubt it, but I am routinely three years late for the prom. ;)

Comment: You can also use `$.browser.msie` to detect that the users browser is IE.

Comment: @putvande: `$.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` block, or the `#someIdHere` element won't exist on the page when your code executes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/IE/i))) {
        $('#someIdHere').removeClass('someClassHere');
    }
});
```

.. alternatively, you can include your code at the bottom of the page (before the `</body>`) rather than in the `<head>`.

Also note that you run the risk of matching non-IE browsers with your regex pattern. Something like `/\bMSIE\b/i` would be more precise.

---

FWIW, see [HTML Script tag: type or language (or omit both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2267476/444991) with regard to using `language=javascript` in `<script />` tags.

Comment: Toppen! As my question implies and my profile protests, I am self-interested and new to programming web pages.  Thanks! I did recognize the ´$(document).ready(function´ from other things. I will accept the answer asap

Comment: I would lock down that regex a bit. Lots of works have "ie" in them. IE identifies itself as `MSIE` so perhaps `/\bMSIE\b/i`. But again, browser detection is usually an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in javascript to detect ie by using conditional comments. This is not my work, I'll just post the Snippet of James Padolsey from [Github](https://gist.github.com/padolsey/527683):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// A short snippet for detecting versions of IE in JavaScript
// without resorting to user-agent sniffing
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// If you're not in IE (or IE version is less than 5) then:
//     ie === undefined
// If you're in IE (>=5) then you can determine which version:
//     ie === 7; // IE7
// Thus, to detect IE:
//     if (ie) {}
// And to detect the version:
//     ie === 6 // IE6
//     ie > 7 // IE8, IE9 ...
//     ie < 9 // Anything less than IE9
// ----------------------------------------------------------

// UPDATE: Now using Live NodeList idea from @jdalton

var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

---

An alternative route you could take, would be using the conditional comments directly on your HTML-file, omitting the need of detecting anything directly in JS (this is more preferrable in my opinion):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="msie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="msie ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="msie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="msie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Replace your HTML-Tag in your file with this snippet. IE will render the tag corresponding to its version. Then you can look for the existence of the class `msie` on the html-tag.

Note that both solutions won't work for IE10 because this version doesn't support conditional comments anymore.