# Setting image src with getElementById("").src won't work in xsl

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following script:

```
      <script language="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("eagle").src="http://path.com:8000/OA_HTML/1.gif";
      </script>
```

And html:

```
<img id="eagle" src="godlo.gif" width="60" height="60"/>
```

I won't JS to change path of the image, but stays the same.
Why won't this work? In js fidle it works perfectly fine, so why won't this work in xslt?
Maybe there is a wayaround?

**UPDATE**

I have edited this post to add xsl file. Although I don't think it is necessary here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>D</title>
      </head>
      <script language="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("eagle").src="http://example.com:8000/OA_HTML/1.gif";
      </script>
      <body>
              <p  style="text-align:center;"><img id="eagle" src="1.gif" width="60" height="60"/></p>
</body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Is the element returned by `getElementById`? What exactly have you observed?

Comment: Src for image is still /godlo.gif not http://path.com:8000/OA_HTML/1.gif as intended.

Comment: Please show more context. That is, your XSLT stylesheet and the XML you're transforming.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not know where is `eagle`, place your script below the `img` tag. Also need to change `<script language="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>D</title>
  </head>

  <body>
          <p  style="text-align:center;"><img id="eagle" src="1.gif" width="60" height="60"/></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var picurl = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+"/OA_HTML/godlo.gif/>";
    document.getElementById("eagle").src="http://example.com:8000/OA_HTML/1.gif";
  </script>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Try changing `<script language="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: More on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both

Answer (score 0):

Solution posted by @Ishank Gupta in comment was correct:

Changing `<script language="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">` did the trick.