# javascript code not working when language="text/javascript" but working for language='Javascript'

Tags: javascript, html

I have following **working** JavaScript code in my html page.

```
   <SCRIPT language='Javascript'>
           function isNumberKey(evt)
          {
             var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
             if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;

             return true;
          }         
       </SCRIPT>
```

But I heard language="javascript" is deprecated so tried changing  language="text/javascript" with same code as below but not working.

```
<SCRIPT language="text/javascript">
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
   </SCRIPT>
```

Could anyone please let me how to make the code workable in language="text/javascript" mode ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">, not 'language', you need type attribute...

Comment: Your `<script />` tags (most/all tags in fact) should be lowercased.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both

Comment: @j08691 : Chrome latest version

Comment: actually, you don't need either type or language, just `<script>code</script>` since javascript is the default

Comment: You can just do `<script>`.  You don't need to tell it that it's JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

Even better (since it's shorter and easier to read):

```
<script>
    //Some script
</script>
```

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element), emphasis added:

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. ***The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".***

Comment: Why better? please explain.

Comment: @RahilWazir: Because in modern browsers, this will work.  No need to worry about which attribute to add, because you need neither :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat : what do you mean by MIME type ?

Comment: @logan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is the right way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Some script
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>`
```