# What would the impact of not including a type in the script element be?

Tags: javascript, html

I have noticed in our local code base there are some SCRIPT tags without the TYPE attribute in them.

It doesn't seem to be causing any issues, is it not a requirement? I am concerned it may cause issues down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a requirement as of HTML5. If `type` is left off, it is assumed to be JavaScript. You only need the type for other kinds of scripts. Non-JS based script tags are becoming more common. People often use them to store their client side templates.

For example in Angular, it's common to see script tags like `<script type="text/ng-template" id="mytemplate.html">...</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Only if you need backwards compatibility.  For HTML5 and javascript code (not other types of script) it is unnecessary.

[Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both)

> As for omitting type, yes, it will still work, but in XHTML 1.0 and
>   HTML 4.01 is considered invalid.

From [Mozilla Developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> [type] if this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.

From [Douglas Crockford's website](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)

> This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming
>   language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute
>   is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out.
>   The browser knows what to do.