# <script language="JavaScript"> Adding

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition, var

Here is my code for 1/13 pages.

I'm trying to make a quiz where you go to the next page for the next answer, that's why I have 13 pages connected in a chain.

What I need help with is adding up the total amount of % to the next page/answer if you got the previous answer correct. eg.

This question I get correct, should total 8% (because there are 13 questions and 100 / 13 is 7.69230769231 but it rounds up I guess).

I would like the next page answer to be 8% no matter what then if they get it correct... +8%.

```
<html><head><title>Quiz</title>

<style>

.parent {
   width: 150px; /* I took the width from your post and placed it in css */
   height: 75px;
}

/* This will style any <img> element in .parent div */
.parent img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.parent img {
  padding-left: 605px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif,Verdana;
}

</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var numQues = 1;
var numChoi = 3;

var answers = new Array(13);
answers[0] = "Ben Stuart";
answers[1] = "Imran Ali";
answers[2] = "Daniel Rooney";
answers[3] = "Brian Little";
answers[4] = "David Rocke";
answers[5] = "Pamela McElhaney";
answers[6] = "David Hooper";
answers[7] = "Steven Woodhouse";
answers[8] = "Somewhere Sunny";
answers[9] = "Phillip Cairney";
answers[10] = "Stuart Clark";
answers[11] = "Jon Maciness";
answers[12] = "He would not be a celebrity";

function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0*2;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;

  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score/13*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";


}

// -->
</script>
</head>

<body background="C:\Users\whittlej\Desktop\Website 1\wallpaper.jpg">


<form name="quiz">
1. Who was inspired to join IT because of computer games ?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Ben Stuart">Ben Stuart<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="David hooper">David hooper<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Imran Ali">Imran Ali<br>
<p>


<input type="button" value="Save" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><p>

<div class="parent">
<A HREF="imran.html"><IMG SRC="next.png" alt="Next"></a>
</div>
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>

</body></html>
```

Comment: [The `language` attribute was deprecated almost a decade ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both)

Comment: Your question title doesn't match its content. Actually, what's your question?

Comment: Well, Im a newbie to javascript as i have only been doing it for 1 week. So go easy

Comment: was trying to do #1...I got the code of here http://www.internetraining.com/Templates/CKQuiz/ but customized it, and thought if i separated the questions and javascript, and then put them on seperate pages it would work like it does on one page. but no it does not

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unclear about what you're asking .. 
Is the issue how to pass on the score from one page to the next ?

So you score 8% (say) on the first page, how  to you pass that on to the next page so if you get that one right as well, it's 16% ?

If that's the case, then there are several ways to do this :

1) Pass in the score as part of the URL to the next page.. eg when moving on to the next page use URL :

http://server.etc/QuizPage2.htlp?scoresofar=8

use javascript window.location.searcxh to get hold of the part after the ? to work out what the score so far is.

One issue with this is that it would be easy to  cheat : people could just edit the URL and up their score.

2) Use a cookie to maintain the score. You could either just maintin a the score so far, or maybe a map of the score per question. Cookies are maintained per-domain as the web page changes, so you can use them to maintina a state, in this case your score so far. See javascript's document.cookie function on how to do use cookies.
[w3Schools cookies page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

This is less 'hackable' than option 1) but still not secure. People could issue their own javascript to manipulate the cookie.

3) Use a session variable (eg in PHP) so to maintain a session variable holding the score so far. This is probably the best way. How to do this is a whole separate discussion, but you can easily find some example PHP session variable code using google etc.

If you need uber-security, use HTTPs.

4) Don't change the page. Have it all listed as one web page, use javascript not to move on to the next poage, but to hide/unhide the right questons as the user runs through the quiz.

Unless you maintain the current score (or scores per question) in a cookie or session variable, if the user refresheds the page, the state will be lost and they'll have to start the quiz again.