# javascript onload() method is not working on html body tag

Tags: javascript, onload

below is the code

```
<head>
<title>Message</title>

    <script language="javascript"> 
    function MyFunction() {
     ....................
    }
    </script>
</head>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="white" onload="MyFunction()">
```

it is working fine with all the browser except IE 11 Compatible Model. When I run the code it show the error

```
Line: 5
Error: The value of the property 'MyFunction' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

Comment: Where is `MyFunction` defined ?

Comment: You could try writing [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) (and providing an example that lets us reproduce the problem, the one in your question is going to error because your function body is a string of periods, stick an alert in there or something instead)

Comment: This is a terrible practice btw

Comment: `<head>`  after `<body>` ? Name itself indicates that head should be on top of body :P

Comment: Thanks..changed the code but still same issue is there

Comment: And i don't think you need to give  `language="javascript"` in script. Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both

Comment: This code works correctly, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNpZqY

Comment: You shouldn't have to deal with IE not being compatible with correct code. It's their job to make it a decent browser, not yours.

Comment: CORRECT CODE? In what universe do you live to consider `<BODY BGCOLOR="white" onload="MyFunction()">` is correct in 2015? Looks like it's been coded even before Stackoverflow even existed. Jeez.