# Make the JavaScript link hide onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form page and certain items only appear on the list if a link is clicked on. I want the link to hide when it is clicked on and the action it calls un-hides.

This is my test page:

```js
function toggle_it(itemID) {
  // Toggle visibility between none and '' 
  if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) {
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = ''
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="3">
  <cfform action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <strong>SAY IT</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">a</td>
      <td>
        The&nbsp;field&nbsp;with&nbsp;no&nbsp;name
      </td>
      <td>
        <cfinput type="Text" name="aaa" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1" style="display:none">
      <td align="center">a1</td>
      <td>Add-on1</td>
      <td>
        <cfinput type="Text" name="a1" value="Add-on1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2" style="display:none">
      <td align="center">a2</td>
      <td>Add-on2</td>
      <td>
        <cfinput type="Text" name="a2" value="Add-on2">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tr3" style="display:none">
      <td align="center">a3</td>
      <td>Add-on - Daily1</td>
      <td>
        <cfinput type="Text" name="a1d" value="Add-on - Daily1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr4" style="display:none">
      <td align="center">a4</td>
      <td>Add-on - Daily2</td>
      <td>
        <cfinput type="Text" name="a2d" value="Add-on - Daily2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </cfform>
</table>

&nbsp;
<!--- ----------------------------------------------------------------- --->

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Add-on1:&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it('tr1')">Add-on1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Add-on2:&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it('tr2')">Add-on2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Add-on3 - Daily1:&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it('tr3')">Add-on - Daily1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Add-on4 - Daily2:&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it('tr4')">Add-on - Daily2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code is in CF but this is a JavaScript function.

BTW. Thank you whoever wrote the original script I found on Stackoverflow a while back.

Comment: What happens instead of the element being hidden/unhidden?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fhddb0q2/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Please be aware, `<script language="JavaScript">` this attribute is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both), you can use just `<script>`, type="text/javascript" is default

Comment: Yep. That is what i started with and it works as advertised. What i want is the original link to hide. There can be many options on the list and i don't want the visitor to click on the same one twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZKMMFXAr8NV5ya7fBJs)

***Description:*** Gave `html` elements for toggle unique `id`s.  Also needed to update the javascript to get the parent element of the parent element of the link clicked.  This only works when there are two elements to reach the `tr`.

*Importantly, this code has an extra unhide that isn't needed...since we are hiding it and there is nothing to click.*

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="3">
  <cfform action="" method="POST">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td align="center"><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></td>
        <td align="center">
         <strong>SAY IT</strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">a</td>
         <td>
          The&nbsp;field&nbsp;with&nbsp;no&nbsp;name
         </td>
         <td>
          <cfinput type="Text" name="aaa" value="">
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="tr1" style="display:none">
         <td align="center">a1</td>
         <td>Add-on1</td>
         <td>
            <cfinput type="Text" name="a1" value="Add-on1">
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="tr2" style="display:none">
         <td align="center">a2</td>
         <td>Add-on2</td>
        <td>
          <cfinput type="Text" name="a2" value="Add-on2">
        </td>
       </tr>

      <tr id="tr3" style="display:none">
        <td align="center">a3</td>
        <td>Add-on - Daily1</td>
        <td>
          <cfinput type="Text" name="a1d" value="Add-on - Daily1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr4" style="display:none">
        <td align="center">a4</td>
        <td>Add-on - Daily2</td>
        <td>
          <cfinput type="Text" name="a2d" value="Add-on - Daily2">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=3>
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
     </cfform>
   </table>

   &nbsp;
  <!--- ----------------------------------------------------------------- --->

  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Add-on1:&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="#" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it(this.id, 'tr1')">Add-on1</a></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="right">Add-on2:&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="#" id="toggle1" onClick="toggle_it(this.id, 'tr2')">Add-on2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Add-on3 - Daily1:&nbsp;</td>
      <td><a href="#" id="toggle2" onClick="toggle_it(this.id, 'tr3')">Add-on - Daily1</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Add-on4 - Daily2:&nbsp;</td>
     <td><a href="#" id="toggle3" onClick="toggle_it(this.id, 'tr4')">Add-on - Daily2</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
// Code goes here

function toggle_it(itemClickedID, itemID) {
  // Toggle visibility between none and '' 
  if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) {
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = '';
    //gets the parent element of the parent element which is the row
    document.getElementById(itemClickedID).parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    //gets the parent element of the parent element which is the row
    document.getElementById(itemClickedID).parentElement.parentElement.style.display = '';
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly abc123. Thank you.