# SCRIPT tag in Header of View causes view to fail?

Tags: php, html, eclipse, codeigniter, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to load a bare-bones view (I've gutted the content to try and resolve the issue) and I've discovered that the problem that seems to be causing the view to fail (in Eclipse PDT, anyway) is the `<script.../>` tag in the header -

View file with the script tag -

[image]

And the result -

[image]

WITHOUT the `<script.../>` tag -

[image]

And the result (It's hard to see the text against the background so I zoomed WAAAY in) -

[image]

The debug output in both cases displays the view HTML as it should appear, but only with the script tag omitted is the HTML body properly rendered.

Why does the body not render with the tag present? I've checked the location of the referenced folder and it's in the same directory as the index.php file - am I not referencing the location properly? Is it possible the file is borked somehow and that is what's causing it?

Comment: `<script>` is not self-closing tag.. It should end with `<script>....</script>` and also provide `type` for `script` like `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="..."></script>`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ... I f***ing hate myself. Thank you for pointing this glaring error out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is with your self-closing script tag. Your code should work with the regular `<script></script>` tags.

For more, see [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<script type="text/javascript" ...>` instead of `<script language="javascript"...>`
Read more about this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267487/3861639