# How do I add input fields with jquery for multiple inputs?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to be able to add n number of books to n number of authors. What I want to do is this:

[image: example1]

where the light blue boxes are the buttons. I want to add multiple books to a author with the "add book" button.

the code that I have is this:

```
   <form action="next.php" method="post">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add Author</button>
            <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"></div>
            <button class="add_sub_field_button">Add Author Books</button>
            <div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"></div>
        </div>
    </form>    

<SCRIPT language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton      = $(".add_sub_field_button"); //Add sub button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(add_subButton).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

</SCRIPT>
```

what I'm getting is:

[image: example2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code snippet. I made some chnages in HTML and Javascript too. Please compare it with your original one to see the differences. Hope it will help you a bit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var commonPart      = $("#commonPart"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton      = $(".add_sub_field_button"); //Add sub button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            var htmlToAdd = commonPart.clone().attr("id","commonPart_"+x);
            htmlToAdd.find(".addedDiv").remove();
            $(wrapper).append(htmlToAdd); //add input box
          x++; //text box increment
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click",".add_sub_field_button",function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(this).closest(".commonPart").append('<div class="addedDiv"><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```css
.bookname{
  margin-left: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form action="next.php" method="post">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add Author</button>
            <div id="commonPart" class="commonPart">
            <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]" placeholder="Auth name"></div>
            <button class="add_sub_field_button">Add Author Books</button>
            <div><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"></div>
             </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: How do I access them in the $_POST? `echo $_POST["myAuthorText"][0];
echo $_POST["myBooksText"][1];` for each in their respective books for the author

Comment: how do i know which are assigned to which books and authors. For example in my example I have Dr. Seuss and his books. How do I access only his books.

Comment: in that case i think we will have to give index for each textbox. E.g. instead of `myAuthorText[]`; it will be `myAuthorText[0]`, `myAuthorText[1]` and associated books will also have same index number. Hence all book fields associated with `myAuthorText[0]` will have name = `myBooksText[0]` and so on

Comment: won't this overwrite the previous variable with the same index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery.clone()`

Like this:

```
$( "#id-of-input" ).clone().appendTo( "#id-of-same-div" );
```

Place this inside button click.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/5fLhgpho/)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but this gives the nesting that you're looking for and lets you add books to multiple authors. I couldn't get the "saving" to work properly, I suspect the script in your question is not the complete script.

#### Key changes:

- added styling to indent books
- don't show the add book button until there is an author
- add the "add book" button below each author
- add books inside the author block, not the top level wrapper block

#### Disclaimer:

As I mentioned above, I wasn't able to test this fully. This answer is "you might find something like this helpful" rather than "I have fully and completely solved your problem, please copy+paste+deploy".

```
  <form action="next2.php" method="post">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add Author</button>
            <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"></div>
        </div>
    </form>    

<style>
.author_wrap button,
.author_wrap input { 
  margin-left: 10px;
} 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var author_wrapper  = $(".author_wrap"); // Author's book fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton      = $(".add_sub_field_button"); //Add sub button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="author_wrap"><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br/><button class="add_sub_field_button">Add Author Books</button><div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(add_subButton).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(author_wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myBooksText[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

</script>
```

Note: I took the liberty of replacing the [depracated language attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both) on the script tags with `type='text/javascript'`