# Escape quotes from Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code in PHP and it doesn't work:

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
function rebuild_preview(){

     var Title = document.getElementById('title').value;
     var LYTtitle = document.getElementById('lyt_title');
     if (LYTtitle !== null){
     document.getElementById('lyt_title').innerHTML = Title.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
     }
}
</script>";
```

I think it is because of the quotes in the Title.replace section. Does someone know the correct way to handle it?

Comment: what is the desired output and what are you getting?

Comment: If I put alert after the last line it doesn't show up. The code breaks in the if clause.

Comment: escape the ` \ ` as you want it to be seen as  it is. use ` \\ `

Comment: Define _Does not work_ Do you get the script sent to the browser, view using _view page source_? Does it get run in the browser and do the wrong thing??

Comment: lyt_title element should be replaced by title

Comment: Also `language="javascript"` has been deprecated for years. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2267487/2310830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use double backslash, one is for php and one for javascript.

```
 Title.replace(/\\r?\\n/g, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a simple test using the PHP CLI your code

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
function rebuild_preview(){

     var Title = document.getElementById('title').value;
     var LYTtitle = document.getElementById('lyt_title');
     if (LYTtitle !== null){
     document.getElementById('lyt_title').innerHTML = Title.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
     }
}
</script>";
```

Generates this output

```
<script language="javascript">
function rebuild_preview(){

     var Title = document.getElementById('title').value;
     var LYTtitle = document.getElementById('lyt_title');
     if (LYTtitle !== null){
?    document.getElementById('lyt_title').innerHTML = Title.replace(/
/g, '<br />');
     }
}
```

Note the error in the `.replace`

Amend your `document.getElementById` like this and it will work

```
document.getElementById('lyt_title').innerHTML = Title.replace(/\\r?\\n/g, '<br />');
```

Note the escape `\\r` and `\\n`