# Javascript not working. No output

Tags: javascript, html

Entry level javascript that I'm trying to finish. Unfortunately my lack of skills won't let me. I know there's working prototypes of this program out but but I want to learn rather than just copy someone elses work. 
Thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title> 1 </title>

        <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><b> Calculator </h1></b>

        <form id="timeForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Years:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="years" value="" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Months:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="months" value="" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Day:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="days" value="" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="handleInput();"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <p id="output"></p>

        <script language="Javascript">
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
        function handleInput() {
            var form = document.getElementById("timeForm");
            try {
                var strYears = form.years.value;
                var strMonths = form.months.value;
                var strDays = form.days.value;

                var intYears = parseInt(strYears);
                var intMonths = parseInt(strMonths);
                var intDays = parseInt(strDays);

                if (isNaN(intYears);
                    throw "Incorrect input. Years is not a number.";

                    if (intYears > 0 || intYears < 9999)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Years is out of expected range (0--9999).";

                    if (isNaN(intYears);
                    throw "Incorrect input. Months is not a number.";

                    if (isNaN(intMonths);
                    throw "Incorrect input. Months is not a number.";

                    if (intMonths > 0 || intMonths < 9999)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Months is out of expected range (0--9999).";

                    if (isNaN(intDays);
                    throw "Incorrect input. Days is not a number.";

                    if (intYears > 0 || intDays < 9999)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Months is out of expected range (0--9999).";

                    if (m == 1 | | m == 2) {
                    m = m + 12;
                    Y = Y - 1;

                    }

                    h = (q + Math.floor(13 * (m + 1) / 5) + Y + Math.floor(Y / 4)
                    - Math.floor(Y / 100) + Math.floor(Y / 400)) % 7;
                    {

                var output = "Weekday" = " + years + ":" + months + ":" + days + ".";

            catch (error) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your problem? where are you getting errors?

Comment: ` document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;` this is a bit weird. You declare output within handleInput but the previous statement runs first, so output does not exist (let alone it is in a different scope). Also there is an extra `}` after the first statement.

Comment: I got a few errors but I think I managed to fix most of them thanks to the comments in this thread. The latest error is at line 84: var output = "Weekday" = " + years + ":" + months + ":" + days + "."; which is a little weird because I copied it directly from my teacher. Says "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"

Comment: There's an extra quote there. Should be `"Weekday = "`

Comment: I'm down to zero errors now but there is no output. When I type numbers in the boxes and calculate nothing happens. If I check the console I get "uncaught exception: Incorrect input. Years is not a number." . It should be typing it out on the website, not in the console.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole bunch of syntax errors preventing the browser to execute your JavaScript.

If you want to see those, you can use your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to figure out where it choked.

Answer (score 0):

The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, as someone said in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language-or-omit-both) (and its true) so you don't have to put it there anymore, you should put the `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;` under everything in your javascript script.

And you have a `}` there

```
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Whats up with that?

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Yes, my teacher said that but since he wrote it out I figured I should as well. I don't know what's up with that. I have very little idea what I'm actually doing despite quite some effort.