# Google Reviews 100% Width

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Google Review section embedded within a website to be 100% width but I'm not sure how to do that within the Google Javascript.

Any suggestions?

```html
<script language='javascript1.1'>
  var nr_placeid = 'ChIJqdfzoNrwBFMRQ1rW3mNlM8o';
  var nr_width = 320;
  var nr_height = 305;
  var nr_directreviewbox = 0;
  var nr_buttonCol = "abca67"; // Amend this value to change your review button colour (hex color values only rrggbb)
  var nr_transparency = true; // Set this to true to have a transparent widget with no border
</script>
<script language='javascript1.1' src='https://www.netrite.net/google-review-code/googlereviews_ssl.js'></script>
```

Comment: You haven't needed to use the `language` attribute on a `script` element for years. You could just try removing the `nr_width` variable and see if that works. Finally, this looks like something provided by "netrite.net" not google.com...

Comment: Thanks Mike. removing the nr_width just makes the reviews disappear from the website. What is the better code than using script?

Comment: If you're using HTML5, you can just use `<script>`. Otherwise, you can use `<script type="text/javascript">` See [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2267476/215552).

Answer (score 0):

There you go, working like a charm. It is 100% width. Hope this helps!

```html
<script language='javascript1.1'>
  var nr_placeid = 'ChIJqdfzoNrwBFMRQ1rW3mNlM8o';
  var nr_width = "100%";
  var nr_height = 305;
  var nr_directreviewbox = 0;
  var nr_buttonCol = "abca67"; // Amend this value to change your review button colour (hex color values only rrggbb)
  var nr_transparency = true; // Set this to true to have a transparent widget with no border
</script>
<script language='javascript1.1' src='https://www.netrite.net/google-review-code/googlereviews_ssl.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, test the following script:

```
<div id="reviewsmaker"></div> 

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenmonson/googleReviews/6e8f0d79/google-places.js" async></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" data - placeid="ChIJqdfzoNrwBFMRQ1rW3mNlM8o" src="https://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/reviews.js"></script>
```