# How to set ASP checkbox state with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, checkbox

In a VB.net app, I have several checkboxes created with regular ASP controls, i.e. `<asp:CheckBox ID="cb3" runat="server" Checked="true" />`

I'm trying to implement a "Select all/none" functionality but I'm having a few problems. The Javascript is not changing the state of the checkboxes in Internet Explorer (v9). I tried debugging with IE's dev tools and the checkboxes are definitely getting their `checked` property set to `true`. (Also tried setting to "checked".) Here is the JS:

```
function setCheckboxes( state )
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for ( var i in inputs )
    {
        if ( inputs[i].type == "checkbox" )
        {
            // this line is definitely executed on the checkboxes
            inputs[i].checked = state;
            // this doesn't work either
            //inputs[i].checked = (state ? "checked" : "");
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("cbSelectAll").onclick = function() {
    setCheckboxes(true);
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("cbSelectNone").onclick = function() {
    setCheckboxes(false);
    return false;
}
```

A second problem, that may be related, occurs in Firefox (v11). The above JS works fine and deselects checkboxes, however upon submission they are set to their initial state. Selecting and deselecting by clicking works fine as normal though. How do I fix this?

Edit: to make clear, this is **specifically a problem with .net, not just basic HTML**. I tried a basic page with checkboxes and IE (de)selects them just fine.

UPDATE 2: including more information since it may be relevant. I just checked a few things and *clicking* the checkboxes does not appear to change their state in Internet Explorer, but when submitting their state has been stored.

I'm using a Telerik Grid view and binding data to it. Here's the aspx code:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridContacts" runat="server" Skin="Office2007" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <MasterTableView>
            <RowIndicatorColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="id" Visible="False">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="name" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="name" HeaderText="Name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="email" Visible="False">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="sms" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="sms" Visible="False">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="useemail" DataType="System.Boolean" UniqueName="useemail" HeaderText="Email"> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbEmail" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("useemail") %>' /> 
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="usesms" DataType="System.Boolean" UniqueName="usesms" HeaderText="SMS"> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSMS" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("usesms") %>' /> 
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <FilterMenu EnableTheming="True" Skin="Office2007">
            <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
        </FilterMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

For each checkbox, the HTML that comes out is this:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridContacts$ctl00$ctl04$cbEmail"
class="Office2007 input" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridContacts_ctl00_ctl04_cbEmail"
type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" /><label class="Office2007 radfdCheckboxChecked"
for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridContacts_ctl00_ctl04_cbEmail" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</label>
```

Comment: I set up a project in VS2008 - I do not have this issue. What is your target version? Do you have any events bound to the checking of these checkboxes?

Comment: @user1090190 I am actually using VS2005 (Version 8.0.50727.867) with .NET Version 2.0.50727 SP2. No events on the checkboxes to my knowledge.

Comment: Hm, I still can't seem to replicate. Can you post more of the page or is it sensitive info? Something else has to be at play here.

Comment: @user1090190 added some more information - after further investigation it looks like this is an issue with the Telerik controls I am using. I only use ASP checkboxes but I think Telerik detects them and converts them to its own system.

Comment: I've never used Telerik before, but it sounds like they might be laying an element over the checkboxes? If you go into chrome and right click on the checkbox and inspect element does it point to the input or another element?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this question/answer:

[How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)

The for loop they implemented had slightly different syntax you may want to try.  Also there are some great examples of how to do this with jQuery that I would recommend.

Comment: That syntax doesn't apply here. I am not trying to set the checkbox state to the same state as another checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Disgruntled,

I think this might help: In your setCheckboxes function. No idea why, but checkboxes seem to behave differently then...well, everything else.

```
function setCheckboxes( state )
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for ( var i in inputs )
    {
        if ( inputs[i].type == "checkbox" )
        {
            if (state == "true"){
                inputs[i].disabled=false;
                inputs[i].parentElement.disabled = false;
            } else {
                inputs[i].disabled=true;
                inputs[i].parentElement.disabled = true;
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

-sf

Answer (score -2):

The value for the checked attribute should be "checked" rather than true/ false. Firefox can deal with true/ false values but IE doesn't seem to like it.

Check the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Comment: If that was the case, why does it return true/false rather than "checked"/false? http://jsfiddle.net/tdFcb/

Comment: Downvote for (a) not reading the question as I already tried that and (b) w3schools, the worst site on the internet.

Comment: w3schools is often not particularly accurate "documentation."