# Java/HTML form with a multiple checkbox "All of the above" option

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have an HTML form which posts its information to a java servlet. One of the sections in the HTML is a multiple checkbox where one of the options is an "all of the above" option.

```
Mode of Transportation:<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" value="Car" /> Car <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" value="Bike" /> Bike <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" value="Public Transit" /> Public Transit <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" value="All of the Above" /> All of the Above <br>
```

The java page accepts it into an array:

```java
String[] transport = request.getParameterValues("transport");
```

And now it's supposed to just post back the information: How do I account for the "All of the Above" option? Meaning if it's checked how do I forgo the other checks and list everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

Either using `javascript`, check all the check boxes if `All Of the above` is selected immediately after select or before posting the form.

Or handle in the server side i.e. before processing, check, if one of the values is `All Of the above` then handle it appropriately i.e. populate your user answer list with all options provided.

You use statement below to check if `All Of the above` was selected:

```
boolean isAllSelected = Arrays.asList(transport).contains("All Of the above");
```

Comment: I want to do the server side option: in an array whats the best way to check values?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a value by the name All of the Above

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" value="All of the Above" /> All of the Above <br>
```

You can use a select all as described here.
[How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)