# Javascript Checking doesn't Work in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, internet-explorer-7

I have the following HTML edited to be shorter and more understandable:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='All' value='All' id='All' onclick='toggleAll(this)'/>
    <label for='All'> Everyone</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='Resp' value='Resp' id='Resp' onclick='toggleResp(this)'/>
    <label for='Resp'> Responsibles</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='9' value='9' id='9' onclick='toggleDept(this)' />
    <label for='9'> Department 9</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='3-9-9' value='3-9-9' id='3-9-9' />
    <label for='3-9-9'> Responsible Personnel 9</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='4-9-10' value='4-9-10' id='4-9-10' />
    <label for='4-9-10'> General Personnel 10</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='4-9-11' value='4-9-11' id='4-9-11' />
    <label for='4-9-11'> General Personnel 11</label>
```

In the name `4-9-10`, 4 stands for user type, if it's below 4 a user is `responsible`. 9 stands for department ID and 10 stands for personnel ID.

When I click on the checkbox `All`, all of the checkboxes are checked:

```
function toggleAll(source) {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i in inputs) {
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            inputs[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the checkbox `Resp`, all of the responsible personnels' checkboxes are checked:

```
function toggleResp(source) {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i in inputs) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if(parseInt(inputs[i].name.substring(0, inputs[i].name.indexOf("-"))) < 4)
                inputs[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on a department checkbox, department's personnels' checkboxes are checked:

```
function toggleDept(source) {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    deptId = source.name;
    for (var i in inputs) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            index = inputs[i].name.indexOf("-");
            lastIndex = inputs[i].name.lastIndexOf("-");
            iDeptId = inputs[i].name.substring(index + 1, lastIndex);
            if (index != -1 && iDeptId == deptId.toString())
                inputs[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 departments and varying number of personnel in those. Everything works great in Firefox, Chrome and Yandex. However, this only partially works in IE7. For example, when I press on `All`, only department responsibles and departments are checked, a department isn't checked at all. `Responsible` check and `Department` works partially, too.

My question is: Is there a function or HTML element here in my codes which isn't compatible with earlier versions of IE7?

Comment: Are you getting any error message in the console?

Comment: `for (var i in inputs) {` is highly suspect and should be a for (...) loop

Comment: @Jan Dvorak does IE7 has a console?

Comment: @mplungjan could a function's `type` be `checkbox`?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan the one that's emulated by IE9 does

Comment: @mplungjan I suspected that too, I wrote that line according to this question's accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html

Comment: @IsmetAlkan too bad at least one person upvoted that answer exactly because it used that "obscure construct" that turned out to be quite problematic for arrays.

Comment: @mplungjan I thought of summoning a downvote squad from the javascript room instead :-/

Comment: Lol - I sort of agree. Very strange the code which I believe is JS 1.6 was accepted so easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will see the problem as soon as you open your debugger in IE 7 - press F12

`'inputs[...].type' is null or not an object`

IE does not like `'9'` as the ID and it throws an exception when it runs `inputs[i]` with 9 as the ID

As mplungjan mentioned, its better to modify your JavaScript as below. Only modified the first one though

```
function toggleAll(source) {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(input.type == "checkbox") {
            input.checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, was only looking at the for loop but numerical ids are html5

Answer (score 1):

Please never use `for in` loops when you iterate over collections and arrays

You should always use

```
for (var i=0, n=collection.length;i<n;i++)
```

with arrays and collections which document.getElementsByTagName is

Comment: You're the first answerer, but this line doesn't work I guess. Sorry, but I have to answer Jason Jong's answer, which I already wrote before his answer and according to your answer :)

Comment: @IsmetAlkan - Takes time to investigate and give a full answer

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, you already earned +25 rep from me for your effort. :)