# Check All Checkboxs feature Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I basically want to ask this question([How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)) but from a asp.net point of view. There seems to be more challenges to over come when you are using asp.net to do this. The CssClass attribute generates a span container with the class you specified and it doesn't get placed on the input. Along with the challenge of masterpages and controls. I am looping through records and displaying them with a checkbox. I was hoping to grab all the checkboxes by class to perform the check all. I don't think that will be possible. Any advice?

Markup:

```
  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkAll" CssClass="CheckAll" />


<asp:Table ID="tblitems" Visible="false" Width="80%" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                   //The data gets added as a table row.
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>`
```

Browser:

```
//Check All check box
       <span class="CheckAll"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_checkAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$checkAll" /></span>

//Each checkbox that will be checked looks like this
<span class="chkBox"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01" /></span>
```

JavaScript

```
  $('.CheckAll').click(function (event) {
            alert("start");
            if (this.checked) {
                // Iterate each checkbox
                $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                    this.checked = true;
                });
                alert("end");
            }
        });
```

Comment: What does the markup (from the records) look like?

Comment: Can you not just change this selector `$(':checkbox').each(function () {` to `$('.chkBox input').each(function () {` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work using this script below. This not work for every scenario but it worked very well for mine so far. Thanks!

mark up

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckAll" OnClick="toggle(this)" />
```

Javascript

```
  function toggle(source) {


                checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

                for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClientIDMode` property of the checkbox control will allow you to more easily work with client-side selectors, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkAll" CssClass="CheckAll" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Check out the [Control.ClientIDMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN documentation.

Note: `ClientIDMode` is available in ASP.NET 4.0 and later.

Comment: That helps with targeting the master CheckAll box but i can't group the boxes that i want to perform the checked on.

Comment: `<span class="CheckAll" ClientIDMode="Static"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_checkAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$checkAll" /></span>` was the outcome of that.

Comment: Where are the list of items being generated?

Comment: I am updating old existing code that i didn't write. check question.

Answer (score 0):

Since each checkbox is in a span with a class 'chkBox', locate the checkboxes using that selector on the click handler:

```
$('.CheckAll').on('click', function (event) {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.chkBox :checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
});
```

It would be more precise if you wrapped all the checkboxes you'd like to have checked in a container div:

```
<div id="myCheckboxes">
    // .NET code here
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.CheckAll').on('click', function (event) {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#myCheckboxes :checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Karl, I believe, has improved the approach. However, if you want to stick with what you have, modify your Javascript to be the following:

```
$('.CheckAll').find(':checkbox').click(function (event) {
    alert("start");
    if (this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
        alert("end");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code basically selectes all checkboxes, and change the check statuses based on the CheckAll Checkbox.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= CheckAll.ClientID %>').click(function() {
            var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', checkedStatus);
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckAll" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check1" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check2" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check3" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check4" />
```

### Multiple Group of CheckBoxes in a Single Page

If you have multiple groups of checkboxes in a single page, you can differentiate them with class.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication2012.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Selects all enabled checkboxes
            $("#<%= CheckAll.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            $(".myCheckBox input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', checkedStatus);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckAll" Text="Check All" CssClass="myCheckAll" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check1" Text="Check1" CssClass="myCheckBox" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check2" Text="Check2" CssClass="myCheckBox" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check3" Text="Check3" CssClass="myCheckBox" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Check4" Text="Check4" CssClass="myCheckBox" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This targets the outter span tags. If you view page sources and look at the id provided by `#<%= CheckAll.ClientID %>` its for the parent span not the checkbox.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. As far as I tested the above code, they both work fine. Which part doesn't work for you?

Comment: I can't get it to fire. When i view the source and saw the id of the parent tag.

Comment: It might be something to do with other codes in the page. I uploaded the entire code. So please create a new `Web Form` page without a master page, and debug it. In addition, you want to use Chrome browser console to see whether you have a script error.

Comment: I think it has to do with existing code as well. I just got it to work though using this `function toggle(source) {
         

            checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        
        }`

Comment: In javascript, if a top level code has an error, it will kill the rest of the code. You can use chrome browser's console to detect the bad code.