# Select checkbox is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've a html checkbox which select all checkbox after click. But unfortunately it's not working. What's the problem in here ?

**javascript Code:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
 checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('contact_no');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}</script>
```

**Php code:**

```
echo "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='100'><b>Contact Name</b></td>";    
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='100'><b>Contact 
Number</b>";                
echo '<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle 
All<br/>';              
echo "</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
  $gid = $row['gid'];
  $contact_name = $row['contact_name'];  
  $contact_no =  $row['contact_no'];
  echo "<tr>";              
  echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$contact_name</td>";
  echo "<td class='tdhead2' ><input type='checkbox' value='$gid' name='contact_no[]'' 
  />&nbsp;&nbsp;$contact_no</td>";                  
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You should include your rendered html and not your php code as this question appears to be client side and unrelated to the php code.  Also, what about this doesn't work?  Do you get errors on the console, does it just do nothing?

Comment: u didnt use id for checkbox input type..

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html

Comment: @Ashish which id i use ?

Comment: can you show us what's the content of that 'source' being passed in your function.

Comment: Another thing, why are you using name as an identifier? Should use class instead, it's more effecient I think.

Comment: @eggshot I've to get all numbers by foreach() function.

Comment: Have you checked each check boxes with their corresponding attributes, especially the name?

Comment: If the checkboxes are in a form, instead of *getElementsByName* you could use `source.form['contact_no[]']`.

Comment: @eggshot Oh I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name on each of your elements is: `contact_no[]` but in your JS code, you `getElementsByName('contact_no')` - add `[]` to the getElementsByName call.

Comment: I use [] but it's not checked all checkboxes.

Comment: I'd also change your for loop to this: `for(var i=0, i<checkboxes.length;i++)` then as the answer below states, your tying to get the checked state of an event - not of the source (the argument passed to your event handler is an event)

Comment: If you're still stuck - update your question with the current code that isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

for a safety, you should handle event object like code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(evt) {
 evt = window.event || evt;
 var source = evt.srcElement || evt.currentTarget 

 checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('contact_no');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Safety? How is that "safer"?

Comment: @RobG I think he is referring to the fact that `evt` may not be set in some browsers

Comment: The OP doesn't use an event object, and if it did, it could just pass it: `toggle(event)`. I don't see how that's better (or safer) than passing *this*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(source)
    {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('contact_no');
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++)
        {
            contact_no[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One another solution, you can add Id attribute on the main check box from which you want to perform select all action and make the same as class attribute of other check boxes.

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectall').change(function({
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(this)is(":checked")) {
      $("." + id).attr('checked','checked');

    } else {
      $("." + id).attr('checked','');
    }
  }))
})
```

I hope this code helps you

Comment: There is no jQuery tag. There is no need for an ID. That is very ordinary jQuery—it should use the *prop* method and set the value to a Boolean.