# Check/Uncheck all the checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table with information. The first column of the table have checkboxes.
I can add/delete rows with a button by checking the checkboxes. The problem I have now is how do I select or deselect all the checkboxes using the checkbox on the header.

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
      function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell5.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell6.innerHTML = rowCount;
      }

      function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
      }

      function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
      {
        var checkboxes = new Array();
        checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
            checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
            }
        }
      }

    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Start Year</th>
        <th>End Year</th>
      </tr>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Actually your **`checkAll(..)`** is hanging without any attachment.

1) Add **`onchange`** event handler

```
<th><INPUT type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]" /> </th>
```

2)  Modified the code to handle check/uncheck

```
 function checkAll(ele) {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (ele.checked) {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = true;
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7Dqqf/82/)

Comment: @LeonArmstrong Thanks for figuring it out.  Fixed now http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7Dqqf/82/

Comment: Short function:
function checkAll(ele) {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = ele.checked;
             }
         }
 }

Answer (score 17):

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/iXAxakO/2/edit)

Add [**onClick event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) to checkbox where you want, like below.

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="selectall(this)"/>Select All<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="make">Make<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="model">Model<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="descr">Description<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="startYr">Start Year<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="endYr">End Year<br/>
```

In JavaScript you can write *selectall* function as

```
function selectall(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This will select and deselect all checkboxes:

```
function checkAll()
{
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), val = null;    
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
     {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
         {
             if (val === null) val = checkboxes[i].checked;
             checkboxes[i].checked = val;
         }
     }
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/SDpTT/)

### Update:

You can use [querySelectAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) directly on the table to get the list of checkboxes instead of searching the whole document, but It might not be compatible with old browsers so you need to check that first:

```
 function checkAll()
 {
     var table = document.getElementById ('dataTable');
     var checkboxes = table.querySelectorAll ('input[type=checkbox]');
     var val = checkboxes[0].checked;
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i].checked = val;
 }
```

Or to be more specific for the provided html structure in the OP question, this would be more efficient when selecting the checkboxes as it will access them directly instead of searching for them:

```
function checkAll (tableID)
{
    var table = document.getElementById (tableID);
    var val = table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0].checked;
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].checked = val;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/pe4xvsm9/)

Comment: Lets say I add some rows and then select all of them and then delete all. The checkbox on the header is still checked. And when I add new rows they are not checked.

Comment: I solved it by unchecking the header checkbox when deleting a row.

Answer (score 5):

This solution is better because it is shorter and doesn't use a loop.

`id="checkAll"` is the header column

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function() {
        if (this.checked == true)
            $('#userTable').find('input[name="checkboxRow"]').prop('checked', true);
        else
            $('#userTable').find('input[name="checkboxRow"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
```

Comment: `$('#userTable').find('input[name="checkboxRow"]').prop('checked', this.checked);` for a one line version

Answer (score 1):

All CheckBox Checked

`$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var someObj = {};

            $("#checkAll").click(function () {
                $('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);
            });

            $(".chk").click(function () {

                $("#checkAll").prop('checked', ($('.chk:checked').length == $('.chk').length) ? true : false);
            });

            $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
                debugger;

                someObj.elementChecked = [];

                $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        someObj.elementChecked.push($(this).attr("id"));

                    }

                });             
            });

            $("#button").click(function () {
                debugger;

                alert(someObj.elementChecked);

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul class="chkAry">
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All</li>

        <li><input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="Delhi">Delhi</li>

        <li><input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="Pune">Pune</li>

        <li><input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="Goa">Goa</li>

        <li><input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="Haryana">Haryana</li>

        <li><input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="Mohali">Mohali</li>

    </ul>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Get" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkAll = ()=>
{
     let checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     let val = null;    
  
     for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
     {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
         {
             checkboxes[i].checked = 'checked';
         }
     }
 }
 
 (()=>{
 
 checkAll();
 
 })();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxd8o4qe/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mainCheckbox = document.getElementById('checkbox-all');
const tableBody = document.getElementById('table-body');
mainCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked === true)
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(element) {
      element.checked = true;
    });
  else
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(element) {
      element.checked = false;
    });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        Name 01
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        Name 02
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        Name 03
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a JavaScript only solution using the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. We add a `Change` event listener to the main check box and then use the `checked` property to check whether the check-boxes needs to be checked/unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true).uniform();
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.