# checking all checkboxes in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following html page

I want to make a check box at the heading of every column which when checked will check all the check boxes in the column.How do I achieve that functionality? I think jquery or javascript will help but I am new to them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<select style="width: 200px;" name="d">
  <option value="1" id="spanDate"></option>
  <option value="2" id="spanDate1"></option>
  <option value="3" id="spanDate2"></option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<table class="CSSTableGenerator">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>       
    <th>00:00-03:00</th>
    <th>03:00-06:00</th>        
    <th>06:00-09:00</th>
    <th>09:00-12:00</th>
    <th>12:00-15:00</th>
    <th>15:00-18:00</th>
    <th>18:00-21:00</th>
    <th>21:00-00:00</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="8" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time1[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time2[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time3[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 5</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time4[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 6</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time5[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noida Sector 7</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="1" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="4" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="5" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="6" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="time6[]" value="8" ></td>  
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="enable" value="enable">
<input type="submit" name="disable" value="disable">
</form>

<script>
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
document.getElementById("spanDate1").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
<script>
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime());       
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
<script>
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
'August','September','October','November','December'];       
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24) + (1000*3600*24));       
document.getElementById("spanDate2").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To check, and uncheck, programmatically JavaScript will be necessary; though whether you choose to use a particular library, jQuery or otherwise, is your call.

Comment: Yes I know javascript will be necessary but how to achieve it using javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282219/check-uncheck-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-table)

Comment: Add that to the tags to your question, then; and strip down your provided code to only the minimum necessary to demonstrate the use case (your CSS is entirely irrelevant to the described problem, and there's too much HTML). And if you could show only the JavaScript, or jQuery, that you've tried to write to perform this function that would be helpful. Please see "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" for more guidance on how to show useful code in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" value="1" />` at the heading of every column and **change value to correspond to the value** of the checkboxes in the colummn.

Then using jquery, add

```
$('input[name=checkall]').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    if(this.checked === true){
      checkAll(this.value); 
    }else{
      unCheckAll(this.value);
    }
  })
})

function checkAll(value){
  var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[value=' + value + ']');
  checkboxes.prop( "checked" , true );
}

function unCheckAll(value){
  var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[value=' + value + ']');
  checkboxes.prop( "checked" , false );
}
```