# How do I use a checkbox to check all and output the checkbox functionality

Tags: javascript, html

I used a simple JavaScript function to select all of the checkboxes, but they don't output what they're supposed to output, which is outputting emails. Here's the JavaScript to output the emails and the one to check all of the checkboxes:
JavaScript to output the emails:

```
function emailNextWithAddress(chk,address) 
{
    var nextEmail, inside_where;
    if(chk.checked === true)
    {
        nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
        nextEmail.id = address;
        nextEmail.value = address;
        nextEmail.type = 'text';
        nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
        nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
        nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';
        inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
        inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
    }
    else 
    {
        inside_where = document.getElementById(address);
        inside_where.parentNode.removeChild(inside_where);
    }
}
```

JavaScript to check all the checkboxes:

```
function toggle(chk) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != chk)
            checkboxes[i].checked = chk.checked;
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML as requested, the checkbox to select all(using '\"' because I'm using php):

```
echo "Selecionar todos: <input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"toggle(this);\"/>"
```

And the while function:

```
while($infoItems = $result->fetch_array()){
    echo    "
    <div class = \"scroll\">
    <form method=\"GET\" id=\"\"></form>
    <table class =\"table\" id=\"table\">

    <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td><input type=\"checkbox\" ".($infoItems['Enviado']?' checked':' ')." onclick=\"emailNextWithAddress(this, '".$infoItems['EmailGeral']."');\"/></td>
          </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
  </div>";
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck all the checkboxes in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282219/check-uncheck-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-table)

Comment: @John Added the html