# select all checkboxes while clicking on one checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

So far i made a table. Every column has one checkbox. What i wanna do is when i click on the checkbox in the th every checkbox in the table gets selected. Does somebody know how to do that?

Here is my Code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>Spieler</th>
                <th>Rang</th> 
                <th>Tage</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>HELLFIRE944</td>
                <td>Komandant</td> 
                <td>212</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Backfischjoghurt</td>
                <td>Ausführender Offizier</td> 
                <td>217</td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>retoaba</td>
                    <td>Personaloffizier</td> 
                    <td>210</td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input class="checkbox"  type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>chrisi_39</td>
                    <td>Rekrutierungsoffizier</td> 
                    <td>210</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>salpo</td>
                    <td>Unteroffizier</td> 
                    <td>212</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Kaeltischerkriger</td>
                    <td>Unteroffizier</td> 
                    <td>213</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>DnerYoo_sniper</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>39</td>
               </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>panzerzockerundnoah</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>146</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>PanzaSintKuhlMinecraftLP</td>
                    <td>Rekrut</td> 
                    <td>116</td>
               </tr>
```

Css:

```
th{
    color:white;
    text-align: left;
    width: 5px;
}
td {
    color:white;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #3A0505;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html

Comment: @Luke Sadly it does not work. I guess its because my app.js is not integrated the correct way. my app.js is in a folder called "scripts" and the page with the table is in a folder called "pages". I have integrated the js into the html like this:<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/app.js"></script> is that correct?

Comment: @Luke sry wrong person

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$(document).on("change", "th .checkbox", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $("td .checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("td .checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/p5pnj0u9/

Comment: Sadly it does not work. I guess its because my app.js is not integrated the correct way. my app.js is in a folder called "scripts" and the page with the table is in a folder called "pages". I have integrated the js into the html like this:<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/app.js"></script> is that correct?

Comment: The way you add your aap.js file in your html will only work if your "pages" and "scripts" folder are in same folder. Also make sure that you have included the the jQuery before your app.js like this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/app.js"></script>

Comment: I dont understand. Cant jquery and js be in one document?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library not a separate thing

Comment: @Sandro21....it works...alll you have to need to include jquery to your HTML..Add this line to your HTML <Head> tag before your script code " <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.mi‌​n.js"></script>"...you can check the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p5pnj0u9/

Comment: I always get this error in the browser. Failed to load resource: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @Abhishek Tandon and i get this error: app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ app.js:1

Comment: @Sandro21 Try this prefix "https://" before ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> Instead of <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.mi‌​‌​n.js"></script>. Or you can download jquery on your local system and then use from local file

Comment: Ahh the js is working the jquery isn't. I dont know why and i decided to do my webpage only with Javascript. I quess I can make the Checkbox function work in Javascript

Comment: one question. This checkbox is in a table. In the same table i am also using Javascript. Is it possible that the jquery is not working because i used javascript in the same table?

Comment: There is no conflict between jQuery  and javascript, As  jQuery is not a different thing its a library written in JavaScript. So  can Just do some "google" about jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the first checkbox an onClick-Event that executes `document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;` on all the other ones.
If you use jQuery 1.6+ you can use `$("#checkbox").prop("checked", true);`, all versions below use `$("#checkbox").attr("checked", true);`.