# PHP- Select all based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, i have a form as below.I want to select all in working when the checkbox(For All Day) is selected. Is there any way i can do it through html or should i go for php or javascript?

```
<form>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <!--on selecting the checkbox below all radio buttons under working must get selected-->
          <input type="checkbox"  name="day"  />All Day
        </td>
        <td><b>Working</b></td>
        <td><b>Close</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="mday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="mday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="tday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="tday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="wday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="wday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="thday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="thday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="fday" value="work"  /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="fday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sday" value="close"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="suday" value="work"  /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="suday"  /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desire result?

Comment: @SamOrozco i just want that when check the checkbox next to all day, the radio buttons under working for all days ie. monday to sunday get checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with php, at least without reloading the page or making an Ajax request but this would be impractical. The best option is JavaScript; refer to this question, it solves your problem: [How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)

Basically, all you have to do is bind an onClick event on the checkbox "All days" that triggers the JavaScript function. The function then takes the list of checkboxes, iterates through all of them, and checks them. The html (taken from the link I provided) should be similar to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />All days<br/>
```

And then the script:

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('x');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shady7447 if my answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to use a javascript function that would be called upon the All Day check box value changed.

Then your function would be IF checked, run through the list and check all days

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Using jquery**

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7L6fpLvp/3/)

**Script**

```
$("#allday").click(function() {
   $("input:radio[value='work']").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Snippet Example Below

```js
$("#allday").click(function() {
$("input:radio[value='work']").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="allday" id="allday"/>All Day Working Close <br>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Monday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="mday" value="work" /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="mday"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Tuesday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="tday" value="work" /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="tday"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Wednesday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="wday" value="work" /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="wday"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Thursday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="thday" value="work" /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="thday"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Friday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="fday" value="work"  /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="fday"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Saturday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="sday" value="work" /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="sday" value="close"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<b>Sunday</b>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="suday" value="work"  /></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="suday"  />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for checking/unchecking all week days based on checking/unchecking of "All days":

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':checkbox[name="day"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("input:radio[value='work']").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("input:radio[value='work']").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border="1" colspan="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <!--on selecting the checkbox below all radio buttons under working must get selected-->
          <input type="checkbox" name="day"  />All Day
        </td>
        <td><b>Working</b></td>
        <td><b>Close</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Monday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="mday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="mday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="tday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="tday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="wday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="wday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Thursday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="thday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="thday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Friday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="fday" value="work"  /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="fday"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Saturday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sday" value="work" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sday" value="close"  /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Sunday</b></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="suday" value="work"  /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="suday"  /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```