# How to handle checkbox checked status in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple checkbox in my React Class `B.js`:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   inline={true}
   checked={this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus}
   onChange={this.handleCheckBoxClick} 
/>
```

Now the prop `checkBoxDefaultStatus` is passed from parent class `A.js`.

**A.js**

```
this.state = {
  checkBoxDefaultStatus: false
}

handleMultiSelect() {
    this.setState({
        checkBoxDefaultStatus: true
    })
}

render() {
  <B checkBoxDefaultStatus={this.state.checkBoxDefaultStatus} />
}
```

**EDIT: Now All my child checkboxes are getting checked when I click on parent checkbox, but the issue is that my child checked boxes checked status does not change when I click on them as they are already set by parent prop. I need some way to maintain this also.**

This is the behaviour I want https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218069/6574017

Comment: might happen due DOM is rendered before the function is called - try running it after DOM is loaded..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want change parent component state inside child component, then you have to pass parent component method to child component as props like below,

```
<B handleCheckBoxClick={this.handleMultiSelect}/>
```

Check below working code. I build 2 component for your scenario.

```js
class B extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkBoxClick : {
        1: false,
        2: false
      }
    }
    this.handleCheckBoxClick = this.handleCheckBoxClick.bind(this);
   }
   
   handleCheckBoxClick(no, event){
    //console.log('no', no);
    //console.log('event.target.value', event);
    var checkBoxClick = this.state.checkBoxClick;
    checkBoxClick[no] = !this.state.checkBoxClick[no];
    this.setState({
      checkBoxClick
    });
    
    var alltrue =Object.keys(checkBoxClick).every((k) =>{ return checkBoxClick[k] });
    //console.log('alltrue', alltrue);
    if(alltrue){
      // console.log('alltrue in if : ', alltrue);
      this.props.handleMultiSelect();
    }
    
    if(this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus){
      this.props.handleMultiSelect();
    }
   }

  render(){
    //console.log('this.state.checkBoxClick :', this.state.checkBoxClick);
    //console.log('this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus :', this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus);
    return(
    <div>
    Child component check-box <br />
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       checked={this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus ? this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus : this.state.checkBoxClick[1]}
       onChange={(e) => {this.handleCheckBoxClick(1, e.target.checked)}} 
    /> Bar 1<br />
    <input
       type="checkbox"
       checked={this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus ? this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus : this.state.checkBoxClick[2]}
       onChange={(e) => {this.handleCheckBoxClick(2, e.target.checked)}} 
    /> Bar 2<br />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class A extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkBoxDefaultStatus: false
    }
    
    this.handleMultiSelect = this.handleMultiSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleMultiSelect() {
    //console.log('aaaa')
    this.setState({
      checkBoxDefaultStatus: !this.state.checkBoxDefaultStatus
    })
  }

  render() {
  //console.log('checkBoxDefaultStatus :', this.state.checkBoxDefaultStatus);

    return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => {this.handleMultiSelect()}} checked={this.state.checkBoxDefaultStatus}/>
      Check all<br />
      <B checkBoxDefaultStatus={this.state.checkBoxDefaultStatus}
        handleMultiSelect={()=>{this.handleMultiSelect()}}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < A / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: I have written exactly the same code, and all my child checkboxes are getting checked when I click on parent checkbox, but the issue is that my child checked boxes checked status does not change when I click on them as they are alreadt set by parent prop. I need some way to maintain this also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html#answer-35218069 same scenario do you want

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want bbut in my case only checkAll works as individualk clicks does not work....how to do this in React

Comment: is in your code checkAll in parent component and individual component in child component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179309/discussion-between-user-101-and-thilina-sampath).

Comment: wait I will handle this

Comment: please check and let me know

Answer (score 3):

Please using **checked** prop instead of **defaultChecked**
like this:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   inline={true}
   checked={this.props.checkBoxDefaultStatus}
   onChange={this.handleCheckBoxClick} 
/>
```

Comment: Use `checked` for a controlled component and `defaultChecked` if you want an uncontrolled component. This is an important concept in react, and is explained here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
_"In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement forms. In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React component. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data is handled by the DOM itself."_

Comment: @HåkenLid yeah I understood that but I think it was never the issue, what I want is this behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218069/6574017 but in my case since I am setting checked attribute using parent prop the child checkboxes are not unable to change itself.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.
Use event.target.checked to know the checkbox status.

Example:

HTML: `<input type="checkbox" onClick={(e) => OnCheckboxClick(e)}/>`
JS:

```
const OnCheckboxClick= (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked) {
        //blah blah
    }
    else {
       //blah blah
    }
}
```