# How to select all text in case of Android Application ? is there anything webdriver provides to select all?

Tags: appium, appium-android, selectall

How to select all text in case of Android Application ? is there anything webdriver provides to select all ?
I am not getting element for select all . is there any option to do it with webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take all visible texts on current screen by below code, then you can iterate with each and perform your select or whatever action you would want to perform.

```
List<MobileElement> listoftext= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[//*]"));
System.out.println(listoftext.size());

for(int i=0;i<listoftext.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(listoftext.get(i));
}
```